# Create a link to open a script as a text file (don't run it) from a latex document in linux

Tags: hyperref, editors, links

I would like a command such as this:

```
\href{../src/wkfl/vlyUpstrOvrlp.sh}{vlyUpstrOvrlp}
```

but I want the subsequent link to open the file in gedit or the default text editor in linux.  Bonus points if it also works in windows.

Comment: I think that whatever happens with the hyperlink when clicked depends on your pdf viewer.

Comment: if you can run a windows calculator with the following command:
\href{run:./calc.exe}{CALCULATOR} why can't you open a file in gedit?

Comment: Well the PDF viewer has to be configured to allow it of course ;-) But if the calculator example works, have you tried the obvious substitution? `\href{run:/usr/bin/gedit ../src/wkfl/vlyUpstrOvrlp.sh}{vlyUpstrOvrlp}`? What goes wrong with it?

Comment: I haven't tried the calculator but I found it on the internet here: 
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2746
If I use a absolute path such as:
\href{run:/usr/bin/gedit ~/Desktop/hg18.chrom.sizes}{hg18.chrom.sizes}
then I get the error "No application found for opening file of mimetype application/octet-stream".
If I use a relative path such as \href{run:/usr/bin/gedit ../src/wkfl/vlyUpstrOvrlp.sh}{vlyUpstrOvrlp} then i believe it is opening the new file "gedit ../src/wkfl/vlyUpstrOvrlp.sh" located in /usr/bin/ with gedit

Comment: clicking on the link generated by \href{run:/usr/bin/gedit ~/research/trunk/src/wkfl/vlyUpstrOvrlp.sh}{vlyUpstrOvrlp}
doesn't do anything at all, even though that file exists.

Comment: I haven't tried the calculator only because I don't have windows.

Comment: Try adding the line 'application/octet-stream; gedit %s' to your .mailcap file. It may be that your PDF viewer wisely refuses to run applications not said to be safe in your mailcap file, as a safety precaution. Do say what you are using to view the PDF.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I was not previously aware of this mailcap file but I am looking up info on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a small script "rungedit" containing

```
#!/bin/bash --
gedit /path/to/vlyUpstrOvrlp.sh
```

and use

```
\href{run:rungedit}{vlyUpstrOvrlp}
```

in your document. This works for me in Acrobat Reader on Linux.

Comment: In my Linux (Fedora 19) and Acrobat Reader (9.4.1) this actually opens (to edit) the file `rungedit`, instead of `/path/to/vlyUpstrOvrlp.sh`

Comment: I found that it is more robust to give the script and extension (e.g. an invented extension name, like `.mygedit` or simply `.sh` and associate that extension with execution of bash. Associations can be specified by generating a application `.desktop` file and then choosing a default action for the extension. https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9735/how-do-i-launch-jar-files-using-nautilus/?answer=15275#post-id-15275 (at least in Linux).