# GeoGebra files as hyperlink in Beamer

Tags: hyperlink, geogebra

Can I attach GeoGebra files as hyperlink in Beamer ?

I have tried this

```
\begin{frame}{Test}
Mathematics
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\href{run:/home/ramanujam/Desktop/fan4.ggb}{Click for ggb}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2982/19372) and [this discussion](https://help.geogebra.org/topic/command-line-in-geogebra-6-classic-for-linux) are relevant. It seems like you need a separate file containing the command to run GeoGebra, but not all versions of GeoGebra support this method.