# How to link from my PDF to a txt-file using hyperref?

Tags: hyperref

I am writing a presentation using [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) with links to files on my harddrive. Everything works fine with files in PDF format. But: links to `*.txt` open the browser -- and that's it. What am I'm missing?

Comment: What would you rather they open in? A text editor? Why do you want to have links to text files rather than just have the text inside your frames?

Comment: Similar issues have be discussed for example [in this other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/how-to-link-to-specified-page-of-an-outer-pdf-document). Basically, it is up to the pdf viewer to decide what to do when you click on a link.

Comment: Also have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/create-a-link-to-open-a-script-as-a-text-file-dont-run-it-from-a-latex-documen).

Comment: Best solution: I want the files to open in a text-editor (I'm using TINN for R). But if the files open in Firefox would be a very good solution. Rainer

Answer (score 6):

This works for me. The log-file is opened (after a confirmation dialog from acrobat) in winedt, the editor set-up to open log-files. The log-file is in the same folder as the pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
abc\href{run:test-ansinew.log}{log-file}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanx - that´s it!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fairly clear that there's nothing that hyperref can do about this. Entirely up to the PDF viewer. I'm just answering here to attempt to move this question from the "Unanswered" list.