# Filehook, with more included files

Tags: filesystem-access, filehook

Based on my previous questions, I now have the following code (snippet):

```
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\Introduction{Introduction}


\NewEnviron{introduction}{%
      \expandafter\long\expandafter\xdef\csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
}%


\AtEndOfIncludeFile{Fourier}{%
  \section{\currfilebase}%
  \subsection{Introduction}%
  \csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname%
 }%
```

And then I use `\include{Fourier}` and this works. But how do I make this work for more than one file without copy-pasting the `\AtEndOfIncludeFile` part? If I do this *for all* files I get quite strange behavior, so I would like to add the files manually. Preferably only in one spot, but you can't have it all :-).

That is, I want to include more files, like `\include{Pie}` without having to use

```
\AtEndOfIncludeFile{Pie}{%
  \section{\currfilebase}%
  \subsection{Introduction}%
  \csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname%
 }%
```

which would be just verbatim copying...

**Edit:** I have an idea. Perhaps I can put all my includes in a folder `Includes` and then use something like [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7653/). To include all files from that folder (there is no harm in doing that as they only provide content in environments which I print using my main file). The only problem is: the order. How do I set the order in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think just iterating over all files in a subdirectory takes a way to much of the flexibility. What you can do is use a `\include` for every of those file together with `\AtEndOfIncludes` and then check whether it is a file that represents such subsection meta information. So for example:

```
\AtEndOfIncludes{%
    \ifcurrfiledir{/mydirectory/for/subsections}{%
        \section{\currfilebase}%
        \subsection{Introduction}%
        \csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname%
  }{}%
}%
```

Notice that that path depends on your compilation setup and might be relative. To always use an absolute path consult the [documentation of `currfile`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/currfile/currfile.pdf) for the `abspath` option.

Another thing that might be usefull, is checking whether the `\currfilebase\Introduction` macro has been defined:

```
\AtEndOfIncludes{%
    \ifcsname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname
        \section{\currfilebase}%
        \subsection{Introduction}%
        \csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname%
        \subsection{Methods}%
        \csname \currfilebase \Methods \endcsname%
    \fi
}%
```

See also [the FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-isdef) for a reference.

And if you need more complex behaviour you can of course combine these methods.

Comment: Excellent! I have used the first method, that way I only have to `\include` once such that I do not have to type the file I have to include twice. The second method is also a good idea. I will see which one is the best.