# How to automate introduction of section titles in book

Tags: input, automation, xifthen

I'm using Spundun's method for automating inputing the entries in a diary, in turn inspired by Peter Grill ([Using LaTeX to keep a diary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68528/59891)), and I would like to add section dividers by year. This should be easily achieved by introducing an if-then clause with an existential quantifier in it, but I don't know how to do this.

*Clarification about directory structure:* The directory is of the form /Year/Month/Day.tex (e.g. 2014/Jan/25.tex), and each of the entries starts with \mytitle{Title}. The main .tex file is in the father directory of \Year.

*How I think this could be solved:* I thought one way to do what I want would be to introduce a clause like the following: for every /year, if there's a file in /Year/Month, input the file /Year.tex —which would include only a line: \section{Year} (say \section{2014}). Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with LaTeX to implement the solution.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]%date, heading
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\par}{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\def\?#1{}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\StartYear}{2014}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\EndYear}{2016}

\newcommand{\writetitle}{0}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]
{   \ifthenelse{\writetitle=1}{#1}{}
}

\newread\mysource

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\foreach \Year in {\StartYear,...,\EndYear}
{   \foreach \Month in {Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec}
    {   \foreach \Day in {1,...,31}
    {       \openin\mysource=\Year/\Month/\Day.tex
                \read\mysource to \firstline
                \closein\mysource
                \xdef\writetitle{1}
                \begin{loggentry}{\Year - \Month - \Day}{\firstline}    
                    \xdef\writetitle{0}
                    \input{\Year/\Month/\Day}
                \end{loggentry} 
    }
    {   % files does not exist, so nothing to do
    }

    }  
  }
}

\end{document}
```

Here's what I would like the result to look like:
[image: journal]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX. Can you provide a screen shot or sketch how this document should look like? The naming scheme 'Year/Month/Day' with '/' separators leads to problems in Linux, for example

Comment: Where is `\mytitle` called? Within the included `.tex` file?

Comment: In addition to my first comment: Is there a directory for each day, in separate months, for separate years?

Comment: Thanks! I added clarification of the directory structure to the question. But yes, there is a main directory called "Diary" and has a directory for each year, which itself has directories for each month, each of which has a file .tex, named by the day number.

Comment: See my updated solution please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trial of a solution...

I generated dummy directories with year/month/#day.tex files, just a file called `#year.tex`, i.e. `2014.tex` etc. containing the line `\section{#year}` etc, whereas the `#day.tex` files contain `\mytitle{Some Stuff}\blindtext`

In the most inner `Foreach` loop, I defined `\CurrentFileName` with the structure as above and use the `\LaTeX` macro `\IfFileExists` to be on the safe side, if this is true, then the `\openin` code from the OP is used.

The OP clearified the question such that there is a `2014.tex` etc. in 2014 etc. which contains something like `\section{2014}`. This should only be included, if there is at least one file in `2014/{Jan,.....,Dec}`, otherwise dropped. I tried to achieve this by a status counter variable.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%


\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]%date, heading
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\par}{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\def\?#1{}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\StartYear}{2014}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\EndYear}{2016}

\newcommand{\writetitle}{0}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]
{  
  \ifnumequal{\writetitle}{1}{#1}{}%
}

\newcommand{\InputIfExists}[1]{%
\IfFileExists{#1}{\input{#1}}{}%
}%

\newcounter{includedcntr}
\setcounter{includedcntr}{0}%

\newread\mysource

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\foreach \Year in {\StartYear,...,\EndYear}
{%
  \setcounter{includedcntr}{0}%  Year file is not included so far
  \foreach \Month in {Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec}
  {%   
    \foreach \Day in {1,...,31}
    {% 
      \def\CurrentFileName{\Year/\Month/\Day.tex}%
      \IfFileExists{\CurrentFileName}{%
        %%% Test if any of the expected day files *.tex exists, if true, then
        %%% include the year file and prevent a further inclusion by setting includedcntr to 1
        \ifnumequal{\number\value{includedcntr}}{0}{%
          \InputIfExists{\Year/\Year.tex}%
          \setcounter{includedcntr}{1}}%
        {}%
        % Now read the title
         \openin\mysource=\CurrentFileName%
         \read\mysource to \firstline
         \closein\mysource
         \xdef\writetitle{1}
        \begin{loggentry}{\Year - \Month - \Day}{\firstline}    
          \xdef\writetitle{0}
          \input{\CurrentFileName}\par

        \end{loggentry} 
      }{}%
    }% Day - foreach
  }% Month -foreach
}% Year - foreach

\end{document}%
```

Here is a small Linux `bash` script, that generates the files in the local directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

YEARS="2014 2015 2016"

MONTHS="Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"

for i in $YEARS
do
 mkdir $i 2> /dev/null
 echo -e "\\\\section{$i}\n" > $i/$i.tex
 for j in $MONTHS
 do
   mkdir -p $i/$j 2> /dev/null
   for k in `seq 1 31` 
   do
     echo -e "\\\\mytitle{Some stuff}\n\\\\blindtext" > $i/$j/$k.tex
   done
 done
done
```

And here is some of the output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Christian! I tried to run it but it gave me "Undefined control sequence". I'll check it out tonight to see if I just missed a } when copying. The answer you offer here seems to add a section title after each log entry (unless that's just part for the dummy text). I added a screenshot of the expected result to the original question.

Comment: @Questionbeggar: Sorry, I missed a package in my code, which was not obvious, since the relevant command is not called at all. I updated the solution and will look after the `section` you mentioned.

Comment: @Questionbeggar: Ok, happy TeXing then ;-)