# Writing a personal diary / blog in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, templates

I want to write a (math-heavy) personal diary in LaTex. I thought of each entry be a section; something like

> \section{Some title, 2017-01-13}

In addition, and as in a blog, I would like to categorize my entries (via a special command?) and would like LaTex to generate a ToC for every category.

E.g.

Category Calculus

Calculus, 2016-09-01
Derivatives, 2016-10-01

Category Algebra

Vectors, 2016-12-02
Matrices, 2017-01-02

How can I achieve this? I'm also grateful for pointers to similar projects (templates).

Comment: We already have a similar question on the site: [Using LaTeX to keep a diary](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68525/2693). Perhaps that is of some help.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; however, the linked thread does not solve the issue with creating a ToC for every category...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A proposition, with some slightly redefined `\section` command, getting an 2nd optional argument at the end, meant for the category -- the default value for this optional argument is `Calculus` here.

The `ToC` is generated as a separated index, which has the advantage of sorting with `makeindex.

Please note that there are no fancy decorations here for the section title etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[name=cat,title={Categories}]

\let\sectionorig\section

\AtBeginDocument{%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s+o+m+O{Calculus}}{%
  \clearpage%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \sectionorig*{#3}
  }{%
    \def\sectitle{#3}
    \IfValueT{#2}{%
      \def\sectitle{#2}
    }%
    \sectionorig[\sectitle]{#3}%
  }%
  \index[cat]{{\large\textbf{Category #4}\vskip0.5\baselineskip}!#3}%
  }%
}




\begin{document}

\section{Vector algebra, \today}[Linear Algebra]

\section{Calculus, 2017-01-14}


\section{Derivatives, 2017-01-13}

\section{Tangents, 2017-01-5}

\section{Matrices, 2016-12-31}[Linear Algebra]


\printindex[cat]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to index an entry under more than one category? For example, a blog post indexed under both Differential Equations and Matrix Algebra?