# asymmetric margins

Tags: marginnote

I'm using the following to create a diary. Suggested by Tom Bombadil [Using LaTeX to keep a diary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68525/using-latex-to-keep-a-diary)

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]% date, heading
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\\}{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}


\begin{loggentry}{2009-Oct-31}{Snow}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2010-Dez-31}{Water of Life}
\lipsum[2]
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2011-Nov-15}{Cold}
 \lipsum[3-5]
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2012-Aug-24}{Sunrise}
\lipsum[6-7]
\end{loggentry}

\end{document}
```

The typeset document alternates page numbers, odd on the right and even on the left. This seems like good practice. However, the wider margins don't alternate. The wider margin is always on the right. It seems like the wide margin should switch sides like the page numbers.

How?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) likely to be a feature of the class, the manual is written in that style as well. Otherwise look in the manual if that is something you can change.

Comment: Thank you daleif. The class has a symmetric option that puts wide margin on the outer side with the page numbers. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The tufte-book class has a symmetric option that did the trick.

```
\documentclass[symmetric]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]% date, heading
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\\}{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}


\begin{loggentry}{2009-Oct-31}{Snow}
\lipsum[1]
\end{loggentry}

 \begin{loggentry}{2010-Dez-31}{Water of Life}
\lipsum[2] 
\end{loggentry}

 \begin{loggentry}{2011-Nov-15}{Cold}
   \lipsum[3-5]
  \end{loggentry}

 \begin{loggentry}{2012-Aug-24}{Sunrise}
\lipsum[6-7]
\end{loggentry}

\end{document}
```