# Command \marginnote already defined

Tags: tufte, marginnote

I have included the package `typed-checklist` in my journal document which uses the documentclass `tufte-book`.
Now I get the error "Command \marginnote already defined."

I use this command to note the date as shown in this post:
[Using LaTeX to keep a diary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68525/using-latex-to-keep-a-diary)

Apperently the `typed-checklist` package uses `\marginnote` to display deadlines in the list layout.

> We use the marginnote package to display deadlines in the list layout.
> https://ctan.joethei.xyz/macros/latex/contrib/typed-checklist/typed-checklist.pdf Page 32

Is there a way to be able to use `tufte-book` and still make use of this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by making use of the `savesym` Package as described here: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-alreadydef

```
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{marginnote}
\usepackage{typed-checklist}
\restoresymbol{TXF}{marginnote}
```

Did the trick.