# using \ForEach to input chapters in a document

Tags: expansion, loops

I have several chapters in the folder `/Chapters` and I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\newcommand\chapnames{Chap1, Chap2, Chap3, Chap4, Chap5, Chap6}

\ForEach
{,}
{\input{./Chapters/\thislevelitem}}
{\chapnames}
```

Unfortunately, this piece of code does not work unless I change it to:

```
\ForEach
{,}
{\input{./Chapters/\thislevelitem}}
{Chap1, Chap2, Chap3, Chap4, Chap5, Chap6}
```

Is there a way to make it work while using `\chapnames` variable as shown in the `\ForEach` code at the top?

Comment: What package are you using for `\ForEach`?

Comment: This might be of interest: [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7653/5764)

Comment: I'm using forarray package.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks! That worked nicely :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`forarray` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/forarray/forarray.pdf), subsection 3.1.2 “The command `\ForEachX`”, page 4:

> The command `\ForEachX` processes the list of items in the same way as
>   the command `\ForEach`. However, it expands its third argument, a
>   token containing the actual list, before processing it. It has the
>   following syntax:
>
> ```
> \ForEachX{<separator >}{<function>}{<list token>}
> ```

Therefore, your code sample has to be written as

```
\newcommand\chapnames{Chap1, Chap2, Chap3, Chap4, Chap5, Chap6}

\ForEachX
{,}
{\input{./Chapters/\thislevelitem}}
{\chapnames}
```