# Macro not working in foreach loop

Tags: macros, pgfplotstable, expansion, loops, foreach

I'm trying to color the cells in a few columns with different colors, depending on bounds passed as an argument. I would like to have one macro that takes two arguments: a `.csv` file and a comma separated list sub-delimited by forward slashes (`/`). Each element of the second argument will have two values: a column index and a boundary.

I'd like for the macro to build the table from the `.csv` and loop through the second argument coloring the cells in the columns, based on the column index and the boundary provided.

For example: the argument `1/0.2, 2/0.5` will color the cells in column 1 above 0.2 and those in column 2 above 0.5 blue and the other cells orange. I almost have it. I have lua code that handles the second argument and creates a list of colors.

My question is: why won't it color the cells in the below structure?

I know there are better ways to do the specific MWE below, such as taking things out of the loops, but I need the loops there, because I'm hoping to pass multiple lists into the second argument of `\buildTable`, which will then get passed to my lua code creating and passing the list to `\ColorColumn`.

My idea is: to have one loop that loops through each set of column indices and boundaries and passes it to lua, then passes the produced list to `\ColorColumn`.

So we don't have to worry about lua, I've included one example of the color list below in the format in which it'll be produced.

I suspect it's just an expansion issue, but I'm not sure.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{pgfplotstable}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{listofitems}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}

\def\assigncolor#1#2{%
    \pgfplotstableset{
        every row \thecount\space column #2/.style={
            postproc cell content/.style={
            @cell content/.add={\cellcolor{#1}}{}%
            },%
        },
    }%
}%

\newcounter{count}%
\def\ColorColumn#1#2{%
    \def\ArgOne{#1}%
    \ifdef{\thecount}{}{\newcounter{count}}%
    \readlist*\mylist{#2}% star option removes surrounding whitespace
    \setcounter{count}{-1}%
    \foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{%
        \stepcounter{count}%
        \expandafter\assigncolor\expandafter{\x}{\ArgOne}%
    }%
}%

\def\buildTable#1#2{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata%
    \def\selection{}%
    \edef\tempor{%
        columns = {\selection},%
    }%
    \expandafter\xappto\expandafter\parser\expandafter{\tempor}%    
    \foreach \x/\y in {#2}{
        \ColorColumn{\x}{blue, blue, orange}
    }%
    \xdef\theTable{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[\parser]}%
    \theTable{\rawdata}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \buildTable
    {%CSV file
        test.csv%
    }
    {%
        1/0.1%
    }%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \stepcounter is global.  I don't know about \assigncolor.  Anything local will be lost.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: I’ve tried different combinations of \expandafter and \noexpand but nothing seems to be working

Comment: I've been looking at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89628/using-foreach-to-input-chapters-in-a-document

Maybe a `\ForEachX` statement will work better? I've tried it but can't get that working either. From what I've found online, it looks like the `\ForEachX` needs to be split by something, and mine isn't.

It's strange because my MWE doesn't give any errors. It just doesn't work.

Comment: It is a problem because you need the colour to be applied later i.e. outside the loop, don't you? So if it is only local, it's gone.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401370/how-to-interpolate-two-colors-in-a-cell/401404#401404

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure that I did understand what you are actually trying to do. But instead of `\foreach` you should use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`. And you should be a bit careful when using `\x` everywhere. An `\x` inside a macro or a loop is not automatically local to this macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{pgfplotstable}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{listofitems}

\begin{filecontents*}{testnew.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1,  0.28
\end{filecontents*}

\def\assigncolor#1#2{%
    \pgfplotstableset{
        every row \thecount\space column #2/.style={
            postproc cell content/.style={
            @cell content/.add={\cellcolor{#1}}{}%
            },%
        },
    }%
}%

\newcounter{count}%
\def\ColorColumn#1#2{%
    \edef\ArgOne{#1}% <----------changed 
    \ifdef{\thecount}{}{\newcounter{count}}%
    \readlist*\mylist{#2}% star option removes surrounding whitespace
    \setcounter{count}{-1}%
    \foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{%
        \stepcounter{count}%
        \expandafter\assigncolor\expandafter{\x}{\ArgOne}%
    }%
}%

\def\buildTable#1#2{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata%
    \def\selection{}%
    \edef\tempor{%
        columns = {\selection},%
    }%
    \expandafter\xappto\expandafter\parser\expandafter{\tempor}%
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x/\y in {#2}{
        \ColorColumn{\x}{blue, blue, orange}
    }%
    \xdef\theTable{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[\parser]}%
    \theTable{\rawdata}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \buildTable
    {%CSV file
        testnew.csv%
    }
    {%
        1/0.1%
    }%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` work here where `\foreach` doesn't?

Comment: @KevinGregory Because it doesn't create groups - in groups variable assignments are local unless some specifically global assignment methods are used.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an implementation with `expl3`. Table rows are stored in a sequence and then each item is split again for building the table body.

The special column can be decided for the single table or set at the outset with

```
\settable{column=2}
```

It wouldn't be really difficult to do the treatment to as many columns as you like.

Here's the code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
ColA, ColB, ColC
0.17, 0.91, 0.67
0.15, 0.17, 0.92
0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g_kevin_table_readfile_stream
\tl_new:N \l__kevin_table_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__kevin_table_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq

\keys_define:nn { kevin/table }
 {
  column       .int_set:N = \l__kevin_table_column_int,
  upper-bound  .fp_set:N  = \l__kevin_table_upper_fp,
  lower-bound  .fp_set:N  = \l__kevin_table_lower_fp,
  upper-color  .tl_set:N  = \l__kevin_table_upper_tl,
  lower-color  .tl_set:N  = \l__kevin_table_lower_tl,
  normal-color .tl_set:N  = \l__kevin_table_normal_tl,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\settable}{m}
 {
  \kevin_table_set:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\buildtable}{O{}m}
 {
  % #1 = options
  % #2 = file name
  \group_begin:
  \settable{#1}
  \kevin_table_build:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kevin_table_set:n
 {
  \keys_set:nn { kevin/table } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kevin_table_build:n
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__kevin_table_body_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l__kevin_table_rows_seq
  \ior_open:Nn \g_kevin_table_readfile_stream { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_kevin_table_readfile_stream
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__kevin_table_rows_seq { ##1 }
   }
  % get the number of columns and the header row
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nx \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l__kevin_table_rows_seq { 1 }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__kevin_table_body_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq { & } \exp_not:N \\
   }
  % process each row
  \int_step_function:nnnN { 2 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l__kevin_table_rows_seq } \__kevin_table_process_row:n
  % build the table
  \begin{tabular}{*{100}{c}}
  \tl_use:N \l__kevin_table_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_from_clist:Nn { Nx }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kevin_table_process_row:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nx \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l__kevin_table_rows_seq { #1 }
   }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__kevin_table_body_tl
     {
      \int_compare:nF { ##1 = 1 } { & }
      \int_compare:nT { ##1 = \l__kevin_table_column_int }
       {
        \__kevin_table_addcolor:n { \seq_item:Nn \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq { ##1 } }
       }
      \seq_item:Nn \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__kevin_table_body_tl { \\ }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kevin_table_addcolor:n
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 >= \l__kevin_table_upper_fp }
   { \cellcolor{\l__kevin_table_upper_tl} }
   {
    \fp_compare:nTF { #1 <= \l__kevin_table_lower_fp }
     { \cellcolor{\l__kevin_table_lower_tl} }
     { \cellcolor{\l__kevin_table_normal_tl} }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\settable{upper-color=red,lower-color=blue,normal-color=orange}

\begin{document}

\buildtable[column=2,upper-bound=1,lower-bound=0.1]{\jobname.csv}

\bigskip

\buildtable[column=2,upper-bound=0.5,lower-bound=0.1]{\jobname.csv}


\end{document}
```

[image]

A different version where you can do the coloring in as many columns as you please.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
ColA, ColB, ColC
0.17, 0.91, 0.67
0.15, 0.17, 0.92
0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g_kevin_table_readfile_stream
\tl_new:N \l__kevin_table_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__kevin_table_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq

\keys_define:nn { kevin/table }
 {
  column       .clist_set:N = \l__kevin_table_column_clist,
  upper-bound  .fp_set:N    = \l__kevin_table_upper_fp,
  lower-bound  .fp_set:N    = \l__kevin_table_lower_fp,
  upper-color  .tl_set:N    = \l__kevin_table_upper_tl,
  lower-color  .tl_set:N    = \l__kevin_table_lower_tl,
  normal-color .tl_set:N    = \l__kevin_table_normal_tl,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\settable}{m}
 {
  \kevin_table_set:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\buildtable}{O{}m}
 {
  % #1 = options
  % #2 = file name
  \group_begin:
  \settable{#1}
  \kevin_table_build:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kevin_table_set:n
 {
  \keys_set:nn { kevin/table } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kevin_table_build:n
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__kevin_table_body_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l__kevin_table_rows_seq
  \ior_open:Nn \g_kevin_table_readfile_stream { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_kevin_table_readfile_stream
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__kevin_table_rows_seq { ##1 }
   }
  % get the number of columns and the header row
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nx \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l__kevin_table_rows_seq { 1 }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__kevin_table_body_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq { & } \exp_not:N \\
   }
  % process each row
  \int_step_function:nnnN { 2 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l__kevin_table_rows_seq } \__kevin_table_process_row:n
  % build the table
  \begin{tabular}{*{100}{c}}
  \tl_use:N \l__kevin_table_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_from_clist:Nn { Nx }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kevin_table_process_row:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nx \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l__kevin_table_rows_seq { #1 }
   }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq }
   {
    \int_compare:nF { ##1 = 1 } { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__kevin_table_body_tl { & } }
    \clist_if_in:NnT \l__kevin_table_column_clist { ##1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__kevin_table_body_tl
       {
        \__kevin_table_addcolor:n { \seq_item:Nn \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq { ##1 } }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__kevin_table_body_tl
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \l__kevin_table_singlerow_seq { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__kevin_table_body_tl { \\ }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kevin_table_addcolor:n
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 >= \l__kevin_table_upper_fp }
   { \cellcolor{\l__kevin_table_upper_tl} }
   {
    \fp_compare:nTF { #1 <= \l__kevin_table_lower_fp }
     { \cellcolor{\l__kevin_table_lower_tl} }
     { \cellcolor{\l__kevin_table_normal_tl} }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\settable{upper-color=red,lower-color=blue,normal-color=orange}

\begin{document}

\buildtable[column=2,upper-bound=1,lower-bound=0.1]{\jobname.csv}

\bigskip

\buildtable[column={2,3},upper-bound=0.5,lower-bound=0.1]{\jobname.csv}


\bigskip

\buildtable[column={1,3},upper-bound=0.5,lower-bound=0.1]{\jobname.csv}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to do this with multiple columns at the same time?

Comment: @KevinGregory Added