# Pgf foreach ungrouped displays list twice

Tags: pgfplots, foreach, grouping

While trying to give a foreach loop a macro to loop into, I found on [Macro not working in foreach loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432073/macro-not-working-in-foreach-loop) that I can use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` and it was indeed able to loop through my macro.

However,  macro: it returns my list twice. Here is a MWE of what I am talking about:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\xlabelsol}{0/0,1/1,2/2}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped  \x/\label in {\xlabelsol}{%
        \x/\label \\
    }
\end{document}
```

And the outcome of the MWE:

[image: Doubled list]

Ireally need to use a macro for the list in the loop because I am trying to automate the creation of pdf files with a template for the project I am working on. Also, a solution would need to be compatible with XeLaTeX

I have tried to look up how to fix this issue but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for the original `\foreach` provided by `pgffor` (sub)package, its syntax is either

```tex
\foreach \x/\label in {0/0,1/1,2/2} {<loop body>}
% or
\foreach \x/\label in \xlabelsol {<loop body>}
```

but never

```tex
\foreach \x/\label in {\xlabelsol} {<loop body>} % wrong syntax
```

> Again, in the easiest case, `<list>` is either a comma-separated list of values surrounded by curly braces or it is the name of a macro that contain such a list of values.
>
> [https://tikz.dev/pgffor#\foreach](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#%5Cforeach)

Then, `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` from `pgfplots` is simpler than `\foreach`, such that it can't handle list stored in a macro, like

```tex
% not supported in pgfplots v1.18.1
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped  \x/\label in \xlabelsol {<loop body>}
```

Finally, here's a patch to `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\makeatletter
\long\def\pgfplotsforeachungrouped@#1/#2in{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\bgroup{%
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped@@{#1}{#2}%
    }{%
%       \pgfplots@error{Found unexpected characters: expected 'in '.}%
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped@@@{#1}{#2}%
    }%
}

\long\def\pgfplotsforeachungrouped@@@#1#2#3{%
  \expanded{\unexpanded{\pgfplotsforeachungrouped@@{#1}{#2}}{\unexpanded\expandafter{#3}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcommand{\xlabelsol}{0/0,1/1,2/2}

\foreach  \x/\y in \xlabelsol {%
    (\x)(\y) \\
}

\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x/\y in \xlabelsol {%
    (\x)(\y) \\
}
\end{document}
```

Output is two copies of

```
(0)(0)
(1)(1)
(2)(2)
```

Comment: Is it safe to patch this command?

Comment: Reported to `pgfplots`, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/462.

Comment: @JasperHabicht `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped@` has only one implementation in `pgfplots` so ... it's as dangerous as patching any other internal commands of a package. :)

Answer (score 5):

The command `\xlabelsol` needs to be expanded before the loop starts. So you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newcommand{\xlabelsol}{0/0, 1/1, 2/2}
\begin{document}
    \edef\myloop{%
        \noexpand\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \noexpand\x/\noexpand\label 
            in {\xlabelsol}{%
            \noexpand\x/\noexpand\label \space
        }%
    }\myloop
\end{document}
```

Which would ouput:

[image]

Comment: `\expanded{\unexpanded{\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x/\label} in {\xlabelsol}}{\x/\label \space}` works too (sorry for wrapping it on only one input line)

Comment: @user691586 Thanks, this is a nice idea since it simplifies the code and makes it more readable.