# Combining Multiple Files Nicely

Tags: bibtex, external-files

I am fairly inexperienced with Latex and would like to create a special document of paper summaries. I am trying to create a large number of files where each file contains the summary of a technical paper and then combine them into a single file.

The summary file would have something like:

```
\papertitle{The Paper Title}
\dateread{January 1, 2013}
\begin{summary}
 Technical summary here $for fun$.
\end{summary}
\cite{halespiles2008}
```

And the main paper would pull out a few of these fields and display them nicely with perhaps a custom command (and I was thinking about using [something like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder) to loop through files, but whatever).

What is the most appropriate command to input such a file and display only its title and summary and be sure its citation ends up in the references section?

Comment: `include` doesn't seem to allow for any formatting or selection of fields and `catchfilebetweentags` seems crude.

Comment: `\include` or `\input` just input the file, you can define `\papertitle` and `\summary` to be anything (and `\dateread` to do nothing)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Can you provide an answer please?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel done

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: voted ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\newcommand\papertitle[1]{\item[#1]}
\newcommand\dateread[1]{}
\newenvironment{summary}{}{}
% leave \cite as is, or perhaps make it locally \nocite, depending

\begin{description}
    \input{file1}  
    \input{file2}
     ...
\end{description}
```