# How to load input file with given starting string but unknown end?

Tags: external-files, input, loops, strings

In the directory of my latex source there are input files: input_01.tex, input_02.tex, etc. It is very easy to load them with a for cycle. But how to load them if their names are: input_01_noteone.tex, input_02(something).tex, etc. So I do not know the end of the names in general, but all names starts regularly and there is only one file starting with input_01, input_02, etc.

Comment: You could probably benefit from [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7653/5764) (possible duplicate). Also, the [posts linking to the above question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7653?lq=1) might provide you with help.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: How are you iterating through the names in the simple case?

Comment: The simple case is something like this: \newcounter{mathi}\forloop{mathi}{9}{\value{mathi} < 11}{\input{math_\themathi}\newpage}

Comment: operating system is OSX, but I prefer universal solutions if possible