# Include/input every subfile from a subfolder

Tags: input, include, modules

Our chemistry teacher gave us a collection of vocabulary cards which include every term we should be able to explain (looking forward for the final exams). Because just having those cards doesn't help a friend and I would like to create a glossary. At the moment the collections consists of about 180 terms. Considering the size of the final document we decided to go with `LaTeX` and to divide this project into single files so we could work on different terms very easily. The initial setup for the project looks like this:

[image: Basic setup]

Every term should get a single file in the `entries` subfolder. Is it possible to input all files with a single command into the main file? Is there something like `\input{entries/*}`?

**EDIT:**

The files should have the name of the term the explain. Therefore the files won't be numbered and have entirely different names.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7653/2693)

Answer (score 1):

If the files are numbered sequentially then you could use the `pgffor` package to insert them with a loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
  \input{file\x}
}
\end{document}
```

This will input `file1` to `file10` into your document.

If the files have arbitrary names, you could still use a loop, but then each name would need to be specified in the `\foreach` command, e.g. `\foreach \x in {worda,wordb,wordc}` etc.

This answers your actual question, but there may be other solutions to the larger problem you are trying to solve, i.e., making a glossary.  I would be more inclined to keep the entries in a spreadsheet and then use `datatool` to create the glossary, for example.

Comment: Ok sorry, I forgot to mention that the names won't follow any rule. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain what order of the input files is excepted. If the order is the same as the order of the output of the Unix `ls` command and you are using `bash` command interpreter, then you can create the script `runtex` with the contents (for example):

```
#!/bin/bash
ls entries/* > entfiles
echo {} >> entfiles
pdfcsplain main.tex
```

Note: replace the `pdfcsplain` to the command you are running TeX. Probably it will be `latex` or something else. Finally, the `main.tex` file can include:

```
\def\inputfile#1 {\ifx^#1^\else \input#1 \expandafter\inputfile\fi}
\expandafter\inputfile \input entfiles
```

Then you can try to run the `runtex` command or `bash runtex` command.

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions to this kind of problems that I have seen until now have recourse to shell scripts or temporary files created with `\write18` and subsequently `\input`(ted).  But it may be worth noting that it is also possible to use pipes instead of temporary files.  Actually, I am not sure that the “piped input” feature works with `\openin`, as well as with `\input`, on all systems, but on mine (a MacTeX/TeXLive installation) it does.

To construct an (almost) minimal working example, create a file `Main.tex` placed alongside of a subdirectory `Data`, into which, in turn, you put, say, four files named `Foo.tex`, `Bar.tex`, `Baz.tex`, and `AnotherFileName.tex`.  These four files could read as follows (for example):

**Contents of `Foo.tex`:**

```
\subsection{The \emph{Foo} file}
\lipsum[2]
```

**Contents of `Bar.tex`:**

```
\subsection{The \emph{Bar} file}
\lipsum[3]
```

**Contents of `Baz.tex`:**

```
\subsection{The \emph{Baz} file}
\lipsum[4]
```

**Contents of `AnotherFileName.tex`:**

```
\subsection{There is of course a problem\ldots}

\ldots~the order of file inclusion depends on the order in which they are 
listed by the \texttt{ls} command; but I~am afraid this cannot be avoided!

\lipsum[5-8]
```

You are now ready to test the (A)MWE, which consists of the file `Main.tex` with the following contents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@fileliststream{\newread\@fileliststream}
\@ifdefinable\@currentfilename{}
\newcommand*\InputAllFilesInSubfolder[1]{
  % #1 <- Path to subfolder: MUST end with the (operating system dependent) 
  %       character for separating path components.
  \openin\@fileliststream |"ls '#1'"\relax
  \loop \unless\ifeof\@fileliststream
    \begingroup
      \endlinechar \m@ne % cf. exercise 20.18
      \global\readline\@fileliststream to\@currentfilename
    \endgroup
    \ifx\@currentfilename\@empty \else
      \typeout{Inputting "#1\@currentfilename".}%
      \input{#1\@currentfilename}%
    \fi
  \repeat
  \closein\@fileliststream
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Main section}
\lipsum[1]

\InputAllFilesInSubfolder{Data/}

\end{document}
```

In this case, I think that showing the output is not particularly meaningful.

**Addition**

Pretty obviously, however, the options of the `ls` command give you some control over the order in which the files are input(ted): you might want to try, *e.g.,*

```
  \openin\@fileliststream |"ls -rtU '#1'"\relax
```