# Get number of files in folder

Tags: graphics, animate

I am using the animate package and have the pdf files to animate in a separate folder. I need to input the number for the first and last file, but am occasionally changing the number of files I would like to animate. Is there any way to have LaTex automatically count the number of files in the folder?

Here is some example code that hopefully better explains what I am after

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
%
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[controls]{1}{./pdfFolder/fileName_}{1}{numFiles}
\end{document}
```

I would like LaTex to automatically update "numFiles" depending on the number of files in "pdfFolder".

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Perhaps with `bashful` and a tiny shell script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pure LaTeX: (`fileName_1.pdf ... fileName_?.pdf`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{NumFiles}
%\setcounter{NumFiles}{-1} % fileName_0.pdf ... fileName_?.pdf

\newboolean{stop}
\whiledo{\NOT\boolean{stop}}{
  \stepcounter{NumFiles}
  \IfFileExists{./pdfFolder/fileName_\theNumFiles.pdf}{}{
    \addtocounter{NumFiles}{-1}
    \setboolean{stop}{true}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \animategraphics[controls]{1}{./pdfFolder/fileName_}{1}{\theNumFiles}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not have `\stepcounter{NumFiles}` inside the if-statement? If-true, count up, if-false, stop counting (rather than decrementing the extra unconditional count).

Comment: Did you run a test? It would lead to the same problem of one count-up too much, which would have to be undone in the false branch upon the last iteration.

Comment: I did try running it and the output was zero, so, I'm not entirely sure what was going on… Also, I'm not sure I understand why that would lead to an extra count-up since we would have an if-false condition. Moreover, I've tried packaging it in a macro and return `\theNumFiles`. I'm having issues in assigning the returned value to a variable, say `\edef\N{\countFiles{my_path}}`.

Comment: (1) I tested your approach and it is obvious: If `fileName_5` is the highest-numbered existing file, then `\IfFileExists` enters the "true" branch and `NumFiles` gets one extra increment. There is one more iteration to follow which tests the non-existing `fileName_6`. Hence, it is necessary to decrement  `NumFiles` in the "false" branch in order to obtain the correct count.

Comment: (2) This will not work, because `\countFiles{my_path}` is not expandable and cannot be used in an `\edef`. (Any macro that makes assignments or definitions under the hood is not expandable.) You can work around this by passing `\N` as a second argument to your macro. Your macro then sets `\N` in its body.

Comment: (1) Oh my, I'm dumb… (2) I don't understand why `\countFiles{my_path}` is not expandable. Any ref? Also, to pass `\N` I have to `\def` it. How is it that I can _set_ it in the macro body? This is new territory for me… Thanks again for engaging.

Comment: Expansion and TeX is a long story. Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158827) is of some help. In short: If your macro `\countFiles` performs assignments (e. g. `\stepcounter`, `\setboolean`) then it is not expandable anymore, and thus cannot be used in the definition body of an `\edef`. Define your macro as `\def\countFiles#1#2{... \edef#1{\theNumFiles}}` and call it like so: `\countFiles\N{my_path}`. You don't need to define `\N` beforehand.

Comment: I did it and it worked. Thanks a bunch! I had no idea I could use `\N` before defining it. I guess it's used as an arbitrary token and it would lead to an error only if expanded. I wish there was a TeX programming primer to read.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach with basic Unix commands and `\write18{}`, listing the contents first and using the `wc -l` command, saving the output into dummyvar.tex and reading that file to the `\numFiles` macro.

Of course, the shell-script should be much more failsafe, i.e. store it in a separate file, say `countmyfiles.sh` and source that file within `\write18{source countmyfiles.sh}` rather.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}


\def\numFiles{-1}

\newread\numfileshandle
\begin{document}
\write18{rm -f dummyvar.tex ; ls -l pdfFolder/fileName_* | wc -l > ./dummyvar.tex}
\immediate\openin\numfileshandle=dummyvar.tex
\read\numfileshandle to \numFiles
\immediate\closein\numfileshandle

There are \numFiles Files

%\animategraphics[controls]{1}{./pdfFolder/fileName_}{1}{\numFiles}
\end{document}
```

A test with 20 dummy files within my dummy folder pdfFolder yields 20 as output.

Comment: Don’t forget that you can avoid using a temporary file by having recourse to the “piped input” feature: see, for example, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251576/69818), [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249739/69818), and [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249580/69818) of mine.  (Sorry for quoting my own answers, but it’s simply the easiest thing for me, since I don’t have to study someone else’s code… ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Christian has declined my suggestion about using the piped input feature, but I still think it may be interesting to show how it could be used in this case.  Note how the argument of the `\countfiles` macro is pre-processed in order to permit the use of “special” characters, like `_` and *balanced* occurences of `{` and `}`, while, at the same time, allowing macros (or, more generally, expandable control sequences) to be expanded, as it is shown below for `\myDirName` and `\jobname`.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\newcounter{numberOfFiles}

\makeatletter

% Beware: "special" characters like "_" that appear in the directory name must
% be either re-"\catcode"d or "\detokenize"d: the latter method is **much**
% simpler than the former, but it does **not** cope with filenames containing
% the "%" character, or unbalanced "{" and "}" characters, and in addition it
% requires e-TeX extensions (not at all a concern, these days!).
\newcommand*{\countfiles}[1]{%
    \begingroup
        \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}% before detokenizing, expand expandable (and 
                                  % unprotected) tokens
        % We use "\@inputcheck" for the temporary input pipe:
        \openin\@inputcheck "|ls -1 % the last character is the digit "one"
                \expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\@tempa} % space meant
                |wc -l% the last character is the letter "ell"
                "\relax % without the "\relax", the ensuing "\ifeof" would be 
                        % prematurely expanded
        \ifeof\@inputcheck
            % An error message could be triggered here.
            \typeout{WARNING: Could not read \protect\numFiles!}%
        \else
            \endlinechar \m@ne % cf. exercise 20.18
            \readline\@inputcheck to\@tempa
            \setcounter{numberOfFiles}{\@tempa}%
        \fi
        \closein\@inputcheck % note: no "\immediate" needed for "\closein"
    \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myDirName}{some_directory}



\begin{document}

\setcounter{numberOfFiles}{-1}\countfiles{\myDirName}
There are \arabic{numberOfFiles} files in the specified directory.

\bigbreak

\setcounter{numberOfFiles}{-1}
In the current directory there are:
\begin{tabbing}
    \quad 999\=\kill
    \countfiles{\jobname.*}\>\arabic{numberOfFiles}\'
            file(s) whose basename is \texttt{\jobname};\\
    \countfiles{*.{tex,log}}\>\arabic{numberOfFiles}\'
            file(s) whose extension is either \texttt{.tex} or \texttt{.log};\\
    \countfiles{[A-Za-z]*.tex}\>\arabic{numberOfFiles}\'
            file(s) whose name consists only of letters, followed by the 
            extension \texttt{.tex}.
\end{tabbing}
That's all, folks!

\end{document}
```