# animategraphics choose all frames which contain file basename without indicting first and last frame

Tags: animate

I want to be able to select all the frames which contain a common file basename in animategraphics without having to specify which frame to start/ end with.

Something like:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!] 
        \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = empty}
            \begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth} 
            \centering
                 \animategraphics[label=myAnim,loop,every=100,autoplay,width=\textwidth]{4}{directory/common_filename_image_}{:} % ":" to select all
                    \caption{movie}
                \end{subfigure}
    \end {figure}
```

Comment: Out of the box, this is only possible for multipage PDF files. For numbered files, you will need to build a loop with an incrementing counter (e. g.`\multido`) and check for existing files (looking for the lowest and highest file numbers existing) by means of `\IfFileExists`.

Comment: Related: [Get number of files in folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356434)