# How to get files from a certain folder into my TeX-file without knowing the filenames?

Tags: floats

I have a folder with couple hundred figures (and only figures in there): How can I import all of them into my `tex`-file *without knowing the filename* in a code like `\includegraphics{filename}` (working with `LuaLaTeX`?

I would like to have the filename as caption.

General MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
%folder for the figures is `/figures/`

\begin{document}
%repeat from here for each file in folder `figures`
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figures/`filename`}
\caption{`filename`}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53458/inserting-figures-using-loops?noredirect=1&lq=1 could help

Comment: Here’s another similar question that I remembered: [Include/input every subfile from a subfolder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234816/69818).

Comment: @egreg: I do not think that this is a duplicate since the other question and its answers insert figures with known filenames. In my question I ask how to insert figures with ›unknown‹ filenames.

Comment: @LukasCB: I've added another duplicate to the current list; there's a LuaLaTeX answer.

Comment: @LukasCB Most answers in the first duplicate do not assume a file name, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53489/36296 just assumes a file extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Java installed, you can use [`texosquery`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texosquery) with TeX's piped shell escape. The follow assumes all your image files have the extensions `.png`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{texosquery}% requires piped shell escape

\makeatletter

% syntax: \foreachfile{cs}{pattern}{folder}{body}
\newcommand{\foreachfile}[4]{%
  \TeXOSQueryFilterFileList{\result}{,}{#2}{#3}%
  \ifx\result\empty
    Query failed!
  \else
   \@for#1:=\result\do{#4}%
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foreachfile{\thisimage}{.*\string\.png}{figures}
{
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
  \edef\x{\noexpand\includegraphics[scale=1]{figures/\thisimage}}\x
  \caption{\thisimage}
  \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

This requires the shell escape enabled. For example:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape mydoc
```

(where the file is called `mydoc.tex`). If you use MiKTeX you also need to use `--enable-pipes`. If you use LuaTeX with `texosquery` v1.3 or below, you'll also need to switch off the dry run mode manually with `\TeXOSQueryDryRunfalse`. This isn't needed for v1.4.

`texosquery` needs a bit of setting up before use. There should be a configuration file called `texosquery.cfg` which can be found with

```
kpsewhich texosquery.cfg
```

(run from the command line). It's best to copy this file to your `TEXMFLOCAL` or `TEXMFHOME` tree to prevent your changes from being overwritten whenever the package is upgraded.

Find out which version of Java you have. (I'm guessing from your comment that you have Java 5.) The version number can be found with

```
java -version
```

For example, for me this displays `java version "1.8.0_92"` which means Java 8.

If you have Java 5 or 6, the `texosquery.cfg` file needs to contain the line

```
\def\TeXOSInvokerName{texosquery-jre5}
```

The line with `\TeXOSQueryAllowRestricted` must be commented out.

If you have Java 7, the `texosquery.cfg` file needs to contain the line

```
\def\TeXOSInvokerName{texosquery}
```

and, again, the line with `\TeXOSQueryAllowRestricted` must be commented out. This is the default configuration.

If you have Java 8, the `texosquery.cfg` file needs to contain the line

```
\def\TeXOSInvokerName{texosquery-jre8}
```

This form of the application has been added to restricted list for TeX Live 2017, so if you have TL2017, you can uncomment `\TeXOSQueryAllowRestricted` otherwise it needs to remain commented out.

Only the Java 8 version (`texosquery-jre8`) was evaluated for the restricted list as older versions of Java are considered a security risk.

Note: with `texosquery` v1.3 and below, you can't use `\TeXOSQueryFilterFileList` in restricted mode (but it will work with the unrestricted shell escape). Version 1.4 allows it, but with limitations imposed by the security features of the restricted mode.

Comment: Is a certain version of Java required? I cannot get it working: `(|texosquery -f ',' '.*\.png' 'figures' Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/dickimawbooks/texosquery/TeXOSQueryJRE7 : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

Comment: @LukasCB I've updated my answer. It looks like you need to switch to the Java 5 version of `texosquery` (`texosquery-jre5`).

Comment: My java version is `"1.6.0_65"`, so I inserted `\def\TeXOSInvokerName{texosquery-jre5}` in the `texosquery.cfg`which I stored at `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/texosquery.cfg`. I updated the TeX Live 2017 distribution with `sudo texhash`, but still no success.

Comment: @LukasCB Has the log file message changed from `(|texosquery -f` to `(|texosquery-jre5 -f` and is the path to the `texosquery.cfg` in the log file correct?

Comment: Yes to both: `TeXOSQuery: texosquery-jre5 -f ',' '.*\.png' '.' 
[1` and `TeXOSQuery: reading configuration file
(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/texosquery.cfg)`

Comment: @LukasCB What happens if you run `texosquery-jre5 -f ',' '.*\.png' '.'` from the command prompt (in the same directory as your document)?

Comment: @LukasCB Just noticed you have `.` as the directory rather than `figures`. Are you images in the same directory as the document or in a subdirectory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58281/discussion-between-lukascb-and-nicola-talbot).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly how you wanted it, but it can be a start.

**Example 1:**
The following example uses the [`tikz`](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf) package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \def \n {3} % change this to the amount of files you need to include.
     \foreach \s in {0,...,\n} {%
       \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figures/\s.png}
        \caption{This is figure \s}
       \end{figure}
    }
\end{document}
```

It is important to note that figures need to have numeric names.

**Example 2:**
This second example is taken from [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](http://How%20to%20iterate%20through%20the%20name%20of%20files%20in%20a%20folder)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\app@exe{\immediate\write18}
\def\inputAllFiles#1{%
  \app@exe{ls #1/*.txt | xargs cat >> \jobname.tmp}%
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tmp}{}
  \AtEndDocument{\app@exe{rm -f #1/\jobname.tmp}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\inputAllFiles{figures/.}% from the figures dir 

\end{document}
```

It is noted that you need to compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape test`

Comment: Your solution makes it necessary to have the files named `1, 2, 3 ....`. I am looking for a solution which is inserting the existing files instead of inserting files according to a given system.

Comment: I added one more example, maybe you can use that?