# \input an unspecified file from a directory

Tags: input, include

I would like to be able to input a file by stating only a directory name.

There would be a directory "mydir" containing several tex files, and I would like to be able to type:

\input{mydir}

and have some *.tex file selected and put into my document.

Comment: unless you use shell escape tex can not read the directory. So it is better to use `ls` (or `dir` on windows) to get a directory listing to a known file name  and then read that with tex to input the files.

Comment: One file at random?

Comment: I'd be happy if any tex file could be inputed, merely by specifying the directory (with no knowledge of the name of the file in the directory)

Comment: Since latex cannot read the contents of the dir, your probably better of having predictable file names and then looping over such a list combined with `\InputIfFileExists `. For instance naming the files `myfileN.tex` where N is a number, and knowing an upper limit to the number of files makes it easy to incluse also of those using a loop.

Comment: @BartSnapp *Any*, *some* or *all*? You're not trying to explain yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include/input every subfile from a subfolder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234816).

Comment: Possibly also duplicate of [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653)

Comment: @egreg I apologize for the confusion.  "Any, some or all?"   I'm looking to just to load "one" file. I don't care which one, but I'd rather not have to give it a predetermined name.

Comment: @BartSnapp: Excuse me, but what does “I don’t care which one” means?  Are you trying to select a *random* file from a given directory?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Ah - it doesn't have to be "random" (but honestly it might as well be)

Comment: @BartSnapp: Sorry, I’m not with you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
    function input_dir(dir)
        local p = io.popen('find "./'..dir..'" -type f -name "*.tex"')  
        for file in p:lines() do                  
            print("Ajout de "..file)
            tex.print("\\input{"..file.."}")       
        end
    end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\directlua{input_dir("mydir")}

\end{document}
```

Compile it with `lualatex --shell-escape yourfile.tex`

Answer (score 3):

You could try [`texosquery`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texosquery) if you have Java installed.

Example (where the sub-directory is called `subdir`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{texosquery}

\makeatletter

% \inputfiles{dir}
\newcommand*{\inputfiles}[1]{%
 \TeXOSQueryRegularFileList{\result}{,}{#1}%
 \ifx\result\empty
   Query failed!
 \else
  \@for\thisfile:=\result\do{\input{#1/\thisfile}}%
 \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\inputfiles{subdir}

\end{document}
```

That will input all regular files in the subdirectory. Alternatively you could apply a filter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{texosquery}

\makeatletter

% \inputfiles{dir}
\newcommand*{\inputfiles}[1]{%
 \TeXOSQueryFilterFileList{\result}{,}{.+\string\.tex}{#1}%
 \ifx\result\empty
   Query failed!
 \else
  \@for\thisfile:=\result\do{\input{#1/\thisfile}}%
 \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\inputfiles{subdir}

\end{document}
```

This will only match files ending with `.tex`.

Note: `texosquery` may require some setting up before first use. There should be a file called `texosquery.cfg` in your TeX distribution, which contains instructions on how to set it up. It will need editing if you have Java 8 (especially if you want to use it with the restricted shell escape) or if you have Java 5 or 6. The default is set up for Java 7 and unrestricted mode only.