# List all files in a folder

Tags: filesystem-access, folders, files

Does anybody know how I can read all the files in a specific folder and use the filenames in my LaTeX document?

I want to automatically create a seating chart with the fotos in a folder.

Comment: Do you use `lualatex` or are able to switch to it?

Comment: I think it would be possible.

Comment: seems to be difficult, any other ideas?

Comment: I am sure this is a duplicate but just list the files (`ls` or dir` on windows) before running latex.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder