# Include all PDF files from a directory without adding each one?

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I want all of the PDFs in my directory /pdfs to be included with one command, so that I only have to put new pdfs in the directory and not having to worry about actually implementing them each time I compile. Like so:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{pdfs/some.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{pdfs/random.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{pdfs/pdf.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{pdfs/files.pdf}
...
```

But rather just have for instance

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{pdfs/*}
```

at the end of my document.

What I currently do is run the command `pdfjam * -o all_files.pdf` in the directory, delete the new files, and have `\includepdf[pages=-]{pdfs/all_files.pdf}` in my document. But this is a somewhat cumbersome and mindless exercise I feel there should be an easier way.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a Makefile that dumps all the file names into an auxiliary macro (space delimited, make sure that no file name contains a space) that is then parsed by LaTeX.

The Makefile, change `my_latex_file.tex` to the actual file name of your .tex-file (*important*: the indents in Makefiles have to be a tabulator, not spaces)

```py
PDFS = $(wildcard pdfs/*.pdf)
TEX = pdflatex

main: my_latex_file.tex $(PDFS)
    $(TEX) -jobname="$(<:%.tex=%)" "\def\mypdffiles{$(PDFS)}\input{$<}"
```

And a small LaTeX file that includes every PDF contained in the macro `\mypdffiles` (if it is defined):

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_elade_pdf_files_seq
\msg_new:nnn { elade } { missing-macro }
  { The~macro~#1 doesn't~exist. }
\NewDocumentCommand \IncludePDFs { O{} }
  {
    \cs_if_exist:NTF \mypdffiles
      {
        \seq_set_split:NnV \l_elade_pdf_files_seq { ~ } \mypdffiles
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_elade_pdf_files_seq
          {
            \includepdf [ { #1 } ] { ##1 }
          }
      }
      { \msg_error:nnn { elade } { missing-macro } { \mypdffiles } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\IncludePDFs[pages=-]
\end{document}
```

Then compile using `make` instead of `pdflatex` (or whichever version). You might have to extent the Makefile a bit to cover everything or set it up to call `arara` if you should prefer this.