# Struggling to Implement FileSystem Based Includes

Tags: external-files, latexmk, filesystem-access, file-lookup

I'm trying to follow along with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24505/145456) to automagically include files based on the filesystem hierarchy.

My file structure looks like:

```
article.tex
sections/
|-- 00-introductions.tex
|-- 10-data.tex
|-- 20-analysis.tex
|-- 90-conclusions.tex
|-- data/
|   |-- 00-xxx.tex 
|   |-- NN-xxx.tex
|
|-- analysis/
    |-- 00-xxx.tex
    |-- NN-xxx.tex
```

So I want to include everything inside `sections` in `article.tex`, everything in `sections/data` in `10-data.tex`, and everything in `sections/analysis` in `20-analysis.tex`. For the purposes of this question, let's just focus on `article.tex`.

In an attempt to follow the linked answer, I've created the following bash script to generate a list of the appropriate files:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
ls -mp sections/ | grep -v / | tr ' ' '\n' > sections.list
```

And I've added this to my `.latexmkrc` so that it runs on every build (this bit works). It outputs the following (the new line is there if that's relevant):

```
00-introduction.tex,
10-data.tex,
20-analysis.tex,
30-conclusions.tex,
```

I've also tried an alternative that didn't have the commas appended.

My `articles.tex` (sans cruft) looks like this:

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand*{\listofsections}{\input{sections.list}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \c in \listofsections {%
    \input{sections/\c}%
}%

\end{document}
```

And if I just output `\listofsections` it looks fine to me:

[image: file list]

It looks as though something's wrong in my definition of the loop as these errors are popping up in the logs:

> /home/james/repos/discos-paper/article.tex:28: Missing endcsname
> inserted. 
> let  l.28 }
> % /home/james/repos/discos-paper/article.tex:28: Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.  ???
> ! LaTeX3 Error: let invalid in file name. Lost: reserved@d =... l.28 }
> % /home/james/repos/discos-paper/article.tex:28: Missing endcsname inserted. 
> let  l.28 }
> % /home/james/repos/discos-paper/article.tex:28: Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.  ???
> ! LaTeX3 Error: let invalid in file name. Lost: reserved@d =... l.28 }
> % /home/james/repos/discos-paper/article.tex:28: Missing endcsname inserted. 
> let  l.28 }
> % /home/james/repos/discos-paper/article.tex:28: Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.  ???
> ! LaTeX3 Error: let invalid in file name. Lost: reserved@d =... l.28 }
> %
>
> ! LaTeX Error: File `sections/.tex' not found.

What have I missed here?

---

Edit 1:

For some reason, it seems as though my \listofsections is coming through as a single item and the iterator is only being called once...

I've also now tried editing the list file to be:

```
00-introduction.tex,10-data.tex,20-analysis.tex,30-conclusions.tex
```

Which still doesn't work, nor does it work if I place that in the `\newcommand` but curiously does if I copy the contents straight into the foreach loop... So I'm really not sure what's going wrong if I'm honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `sections.list` has one filename per line (no comma)

```
00-introduction.tex
10-data.tex
20-analysis.tex
30-conclusions.tex
```

You can simply read one line at a time to get the filename, then input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newread\sections
\openin\sections=sections.list
\begin{document}

\loop
{\endlinechar=-1 \global\read\sections to \next}
\ifx\next\empty\else
\input{\next}
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does seem to work, but I'd appreciate it if you could explain the syntax and commands you've used a little more

Comment: `\read` is a tex primitive whch reads one line of a file then assigns it to a macro so it is like `\newcommand\next{00-introduction.tex}` on the first iteration. On  the last it is empty so matches `\empty` and the loop stops @ScottishTapWater

Comment: @ScottishTapWater documentation in e.g. TeXbook or TeX by Topic. Although if the file names might contain "special characters" you might consider using `\readline` whose "documentation" (actually not documentation, more like "brief description") is in the ε-TeX manual

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Quick follow up, I've tried to add a nested version of this to add files in `sections/data` to `10-data` (which works) but then the outer-loop doesn't seem to continue... Would you have any idea why this might be or should I make a fresh question?

Comment: Actually, I've made a new question, it's here if you've got any ideas https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666649/nested-include-loop-acting-strangely

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `\foreach` is the right tool, as it executes every item in the loop in a group.

You aren't defining `\listofsections` as the list, but as a command that inputs a file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-sections.list}
00-introduction.tex,
10-data.tex,
20-analysis.tex,
30-conclusions.tex,
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\CatchFileDef{\listofsections}{\jobname-sections.list}{}

\begin{document}

\foreach \c in \listofsections {%
  \if\relax\c\relax
  \else
    %\input{sections/\c}%
    I would input ``sections/\c''\endgraf
  \fi
}

\end{document}
```

I changed the name just to keep filenames distinguished in my “tryout” folder and used a “mock `\input`'' just to show what happens. The `\if\relax\c\relax` is needed to avoid a spurious final input.

[image]

My preferred way would be

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-sections.list}
00-introduction.tex,
10-data.tex,
20-analysis.tex,
30-conclusions.tex,
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\inputfromlist}{m}
 {% #1 is the name of the file containing the list
  % store the contents of the file in \l_tmpa_tl
  \file_get:nnN { #1 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  % transform the tl into a clist
  \clist_set:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl
  % cycle through the items i the list
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
   {
    %\input{##1}
    I~would~input~``sections/##1''\par
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\inputfromlist{\jobname-sections.list}

\end{document}
```

The function `\file_get:nnN` is the `expl3` analog of `\CatchFileDef`. I then transform the contents into a clist (empty items are automatically removed) and map it.

What does `\clist_set:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl` do? It is the same as

```
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { <contents of \l_tmpa_tl> }
```

The `\clist_set:Nn` function does a normalization, so empty items (that is, consisting of zero or more spaces) are removed.

Finally, the `\clist_map_inline:Nn` function loops over the list's items. The current item is denoted by `#1`, but, since we're inside the definition of a command, we must use `##1`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the syntax you're using? I'm not familiar with `expl3`

Comment: @ScottishTapWater I added a few comments

Answer (score 1):

If doing this without packages I might have TeX switch to verbatim-catcode-régime with `\endlinechar` denoting the number of the code-point of the carriage-return-character and input the file list via expandable `\@@input` and process it as a list of carriage-return-delimited arguments.

*(The internal character encoding scheme with traditional TeX is ASCII. The internal character encoding scheme with LuaTeX and XeTeX  is unicode whereof ASCII is a strict subset. The number of the code-point of the carriage-return-character is 13 both in ASCII and in unicode. In .tex-input-files the carriage-return-character can be denoted in TeX's `^^`-notation via `^^M`; M is the 13<sup>th</sup> letter in the latin alphabet. `^^`-notation requires category-code 7(superscript) to be assigned to the character `^`, which is the default.)*

This way filenames are read under verbatim-catcode-régime. This might be a feature in case filenames contain sequences of space characters and/or characters like `^` etc that usually are/might be treated in special ways by TeX or—like `{` and `}`—need to be balanced when occurring within macro-arguments like the argument of the macro `\input`.

`\futurelet` is used only to ensure that TeX looks ahead and hereby removes the eof-token at the end of the file which otherwise might trigger a `file ended while scanning the use of...`-error when `\inputfileloop` grabs the last/appended `\relax`-dummy-line which marks the end of the loop.  (Alternatively one could use `\everyeof` for appending the last dummy-line.)

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_inputfiles.txt}
00-introduction.tex
10-data.tex
20-analysis.tex
30-conclusions.tex
40-weird}%}  {^#^^61^^!.tex
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\makeatletter\endlinechar=-1\relax\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\inputfiles{mv}{%
     \begingroup
     \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\do\^^M\do\^^I%
     %\endlinechar=`\^^M\relax %<- This is the default, thus this line is turned into a comment.
     \def\temp{\inputfileloop{}{#2}}%
     \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\tempb\expandafter\temp\@@input "#1" \relax^^M%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\inputfileloop{%
    % recursively in #1 accumulate a list of \input-commands
    %   #1 list of \input-commands gathered so far
    %   #2 directory
    %   #3 filename or \relax-token to process in this iteration.
    \long\def\inputfileloop#1#2#3^^M{%
      \ifx\relax#3\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi
      % Use this for inputting:
      %{\def\temp{\inputfileloop{#1\input{#2#3}}{#2}}\futurelet\tempb\temp}{\endgroup#1}%
      % Use this for message on terminal instead of inputting:
      {\def\temp{\inputfileloop{#1\message{I would \string\input{#2#3}^^J}}{#2}}\futurelet\tempb\temp}{\endgroup#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\inputfiles{\jobname_inputfiles.txt}{section/}

\end{document}
```

Messages on terminal are:

```
I would \input{section/00-introduction.tex}
I would \input{section/10-data.tex}
I would \input{section/20-analysis.tex}
I would \input{section/30-conclusions.tex}
I would \input{section/40-weird}%}  {^#^^61^^!.tex}
```

With the last message the argument of the `\input`-command is:
`section/section/40-weird}%}␣␣{^#^^61^^!.tex`
(`␣` denotes a space character.)

The token-sequence forming that argument is tokenized under verbatim-category-code-régime, so

- several spaces don't collapse into a single one.
- `^^`-notation is disabled, i.e., `^^61^^!` is not tokenized as `aa`
- `{` and `}` are not treated as braces for scoping/denoting arguments but are treaated as ordinary characters.
- `#` is treated as an ordinary character which can be used without doubling within arguments of macros which define scratch-macros from their arguments.
- `%` is treated as an ordinary character

---

It just occurred to me that you might like to crank out empty lines when the file holding the list of input-files is processed:

```latex
% Let's within the current directory/folder create the file holding
% the list of input-files:

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_inputfiles.txt}
00-introduction.tex
10-data.tex
20-analysis.tex
30-conclusions.tex

mysubsection/40-bla.tex
50-weird}%}  {^#^^61^^!.tex
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\makeatletter\endlinechar=-1\relax\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\inputfiles{mv}{%
     \begingroup
     \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\do\^^M\do\^^I%
     %\endlinechar=`\^^M\relax %<- This is the default, thus this line is turned into a comment.
     \def\temp{\inputfileloop{}{#2}}%
     \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\tempb\expandafter\temp\@@input "#1" \relax^^M%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\inputfileloop{%
    % recursively in #1 accumulate a list of \input-commands
    %   #1 list of \input-commands gathered so far
    %   #2 directory;  slash etc needs to be included so you can leave it empty if you like.
    %   #3 filename or \relax-token to process in this iteration.
    \long\def\inputfileloop#1#2#3^^M{%
      \ifx\relax#3\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi
      {%
        \def\temp{%
          \ifcat$\detokenize{#3}$\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\inputfileappendtolist\fi
          {#3}\inputfileloop{#1}{#2}%
        }%
        \futurelet\tempb\temp
      }{\endgroup#1}%
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\inputfileappendtolist[4]{%
    #2{#3%
      % Use this for inputting:
      %\input{#4#1}%
      % Use this for message on terminal instead of inputting:
      \message{I would \string\input{#4#1}^^J}%
    }{#4}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\inputfiles{\jobname_inputfiles.txt}{mysection/}

\end{document}
```

Messages on terminal are:

```
I would \input{mysection/00-introduction.tex}
I would \input{mysection/10-data.tex}
I would \input{mysection/20-analysis.tex}
I would \input{mysection/30-conclusions.tex}
I would \input{mysection/mysubsection/40-bla.tex}
I would \input{mysection/50-weird}%}  {^#^^61^^!.tex}
```

With the last message the argument of the `\input`-command is:
`mysection/50-weird}%}␣␣{^#^^61^^!.tex`
(`␣` denotes a space character.)