# Nested Include Loop Acting Strangely

Tags: latex3, loops, filesystem-access

I'm trying to implement filesystem based file includes for a paper I'm writing and have previously asked a question on this topic. The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665899/145456) seems to work in the case that I only have a single discovery loop. However, If I try and nest these, it behaves weirdly.

---

So to replicate some details from the original question:

My filesystem looks like this:

```
article.tex
sections/
|-- 00-introductions.tex
|-- 10-data.tex
|-- 20-analysis.tex
|-- 90-conclusions.tex
|-- data/
|   |-- 00-xxx.tex 
|   |-- NN-xxx.tex
|
|-- analysis/
    |-- 00-xxx.tex
    |-- NN-xxx.tex
```

And my `article.tex` now looks like:

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{article}

\input{packages.tex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{xxx}

\author{xxx}
\date{\today}

\newread\sections
\openin\sections=build/sections.list

\newread\data
\openin\data=build/data.list

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
     {\lipsum[1-2]}
     \bigskip
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]


\loop
{\endlinechar=-1 \global\read\sections to \next}
\ifx\next\empty\else
\input{sections/\next}
\repeat

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

So, as things stand, this includes all of the files in `/sections` quite well.

However, I'd also like to include everything in `/sections/data` into `10-data.tex`, so I've added this to the file:

```tex
\section{Data}

\loop
{\endlinechar=-1 \global\read\data to \next}
\ifx\next\empty\else
\input{sections/data/\next}
\repeat
```

However, this results in the introduction and data sections being discovered and all of the subsections in `/data/sections` but then it stops. For some reason, the outer loop doesn't then seem to add `20-analysis.tex` or `90-conclusions.tex` to `article.tex`. The outer loop just seems to stop.

What's going on here? Does LaTex just not support nested loops? Is there a way around this?

Comment: It's in `build/data.list` and opened at the top of `article.tex`, right below where I do it for sections. It's generated in exactly the same way as sections. The fact that it's including the data sections would imply to me that it's being opened and read just fine

Comment: you probably want `{\input{sections/\next}}` to keep the inner loop local (or use a different loop macro})

Comment: That's done it, thank you! Do you want me to write up an answer or leave it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though `\input{}` doesn't create a new scope on its own.

To fix this, you can just wrap it in braces like so:

```tex
\loop
{\endlinechar=-1 \global\read\sections to \next}
\ifx\next\empty\else
{\input{sections/\next}}
\repeat
```

As a side note, if you're planning on re-using this functionality, it can be wrapped up in a newcommand:

```tex
% Include every file in a directory based on an externally generated list of file-names.
% #0 - Iterator name
% #1 - List of files to include
% #2 - Directory the files are in
\newcommand{\IncludeFromDirectory}[3]{%
\newread#1
\openin#1=#2

\loop
{\endlinechar=-1 \global\read#1 to \next}
\ifx\next\empty\else
{\input{#3/\next}}
\repeat
}
```

And then used like:

```tex
\IncludeFromDirectory{\sections}{build/sections.list}{sections}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `\input` inside a group may not be the best idea.

Here's the structure I built:

```
├── article.aux
├── article.log
├── article.pdf
├── article.tex
├── data.list
├── sections
│   ├── 00-introductions.tex
│   ├── 10-data.tex
│   ├── 20-analysis.tex
│   ├── 90-conclusions.tex
│   ├── analysis
│   └── data
│       ├── 00-xxx.tex
│       └── NN-xxx.tex
└── sections.list
```

The file `sections.list` is

```
00-introductions.tex
10-data.tex
20-analysis.tex
90-conclusions.tex
```

and `data.list` is

```
00-xxx.tex 
NN-xxx.tex
```

The `.tex` files just contain `I'm \textt{<filename>}` with the exception of `10-data.tex` that has

```
I'm \texttt{10-data.tex}

\inputfromlist[sections/data]{data.list}
```

and, of course, `article.tex` that has

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\inputfromlist}{O{.}m}
 {% #1 = prefix (default current directory)
  % #2 = file list
  \scottishtapwater_lists:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_scottishtapwater_lists_files_ior
\int_new:N \g_scottishtapwater_lists_level_int

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Nn \__scottishtapwater_lists_level:
 {
  g_scottishtapwater_lists_files_ \int_eval:n { \g_scottishtapwater_lists_level_int } _seq
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \scottishtapwater_lists:nn
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_scottishtapwater_lists_level_int
  \seq_gclear_new:c { \__scottishtapwater_lists_level: }
  \ior_open:Nn \g_scottishtapwater_lists_files_ior { #2 }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_scottishtapwater_lists_files_ior
   {
    \seq_gput_right:cn { \__scottishtapwater_lists_level: } { ##1 }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g_scottishtapwater_lists_files_ior
  \seq_map_inline:cn { \__scottishtapwater_lists_level: }
   {
    \tl_if_empty:nF { ##1 } { \input{#1/##1} \par }
   }
  \int_gdecr:N \g_scottishtapwater_lists_level_int
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\inputfromlist[sections]{sections.list}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to read the lists line by line and to populate with them a sequence that depends on the level provided by the integer variable `\g_scottishtapwater_lists_level_int`. Thus we can nest as many `\inputfromlist` commands as we want without introducing unwanted grouping.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why that first sentence is the case?