# Redefine command when inside a specific other command possible?

Tags: macros, conditionals, nesting

How, in general, can I (re)define commands based on in which other command they are nested?

A more specific example: I have a custom latex command (say, `\code{}`)  that makes text appear bold. However, when used inside another custom command (such as in `\question{Will you use \code{command 1} or \code{command 2}?}`), I want the `\code{}` text to be NOT bold. So I want to redefine `\code{}` when inside another command.

BTW: When using CSS to format HTML pages, it would go something like this:

```css
.code {font-weight: bold;}
.question .code {font-weight: normal;}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
\newcommand\question[1]{{% extra brace
  \renewcommand\code[1]{\textit{##1}}% double #
  whatever you want for #1}}
```

Comment: Real application of this trick can be seen here too : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/how-to-include-all-files-within-a-directory-relative-to-the-edited-tex-file/6548#6548

Comment: Note that above link is to an answer which has been deleted.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I find the brace too easy to overlook most of the time so I use `\begingroup`…`\endgroup` instead:

```
\newcommand\question[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\code[1]{\textit{##1}}% double #
    whatever you want for #1%
  \endgroup}
```

Comment: I agree, and the distinction can be important when defining material to be used in math mode. BTW, no comment char is required after the `\begingroup`.

Comment: @Will: I’m never sure where the newline is swallowed so when in doubt, I add it.

Comment: Just consider a newline to be a space — in which case, the rule is that spaces after multi-letter control sequences are always swallowed. (And spaces between macro arguments.)

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\let\code\textbf
\newcommand\question[1]{{\itshape#1}}
\begin{document}

\question{Will you use \code{command 1} or \code{command 2}?}

\question{\let\code\textnormal Will you use \code{command 1} or \code{command 2}?}

\question{Will you use \code{command 1} or \code{command 2}?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will globally change the definition of code, won't it? That wouldn't be good.

Comment: @Hendrik:  then explain me why the third line is the same as the first line.

Comment: I really should switch my brain on before leaving such comments. You're right, of course; sorry!

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that this method depend on `#1` being in a group in the `\question` command. I.e. there are double curly brackets on the `\newcommand`-line. The outer for delimiting the content of the command (not making a group) and the inner to actually make a group. If `#1` was not used within a group, the `\let` in the second use would have “spilled over” to the third use.

Comment: (cont. from last comment) So, for example, if the definition was `\newcommand\question[1]{{\itshape #1}~#1}` (This writes it’s argument twice. once in italic and once in the surrounding style) the `\let` would always spill over, if not enclosed in a group when calling the command. This shows that you need to know how a command is defined if you want to use `\let` inside an argument to it.