# How to avoid text style adoption in environment?

Tags: environments

When I define a macro such as:

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}{a_{\text{sample}}}
```

the "sample" text is italic when used in e.g. an example environment.

How can I make sure it will not adjust to this environment?

Comment: Use `\textnormal`; related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88730/mathrm-or-mbox-what-is-the-convention-when-writing-a-equation

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Redefine command when inside a specific other command possible?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8243/5764) [Herbert's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8247/5764) shows the difference when using `\textnormal` properly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).