# Loop to include multiple files

Tags: external-files, input, loops, filesystem-access, file-lookup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder)

I would like to include all the `*.tex` files from a directory in a document.

To avoid me having to add manually the `\input{dir/plop.tex}`, `\input{dir/plip.tex}` `(…)`, I would like to do it with a loop, like we could write, for example in bash :

```
for file in /dir/*
    do \include{$file}
done
```

I found in documentation things like multido, but it doesn’t sems to be able to do my stuff.

Do you have any solutions for this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: You can also look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20861/4427)