# How to include graphics from a complex file structure

Tags: graphics, file-lookup

I am writing a Latex file that needs to include figures from a directory graphs.

**graphs** has several sub-directories say, **one** , **two** and **three**. These individually contain several graphics that should be included in the file.

One way is to include every graphic in the file manually. But, that is too cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: So you want to include all graphic files from certain directories automatically? In this case see [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder), which looks like a duplicate. The adjustments to multiple directories should be easily done.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Ah. You beat me to the punch.

Comment: You question is not well-defined at the moment. Do you only want to reduce the amount of work, e.g. not have to write the full directory names all the time, or do you want to include *all* graphic files from a certain directory structure automatically? I personally think it is the later, but looking at the two answers so far other people think more about the former. In that case [Automatically Locate Included Images](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/automatically-locate-included-images) looks like a duplicate.

Comment: @Martin: Yea, I guess the question could be a tad bit more specific at what is the optimal goal here. Whether to reduce the typing or have it auto included.

Comment: @MartinScharrer. My main motive here is to reduce the amount of work as I have about 100 plots to include and including each of them one by one is a pain in the bottom

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6547/9467 seems relevant.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain why the link that @MartinScharrer provided in the very first comment does not solve your issue, and provide an example directory structure along with sample file names.

Answer (score 8):

Put into your preamble:

```
\graphicspath{{graphs}{graphs/one}{graphs/two}{graphs/three}}
```

makes sense if you do not have too many subdirectories. Every path is enclosed in braces.

Comment: Hi, But how do I include the files then as each **one**, **two** etc have the same file name like a.pdf and b.pdf

Comment: @Ankit: you can use `\graphicspath`  several times in your document to define other search rules.

Comment: When using `\graphicspath` some common file names are somehow reserved by the system (`left.pdf`, `hand.png`). The list of reserved names is moving such that you should always use `./file name` instead of just `file name` in command arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution. Comments will be added later.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,ifpdf}
\usepackage{ltxkeys}[2011/12/10]
\makeatletter
\ltxkeys@declarekeys*[KV]{importfiles}[fim@]{
  cmd/setorlaunch/set;
  cmd/processor/\includegraphics/
    \ifltxkeys@dec\else
      \ifescapedTF{#1}{}{
        \edef\fim@processor{\noexpandcsn\fim@processor}
      }
      \def\reserved@a##1{
        \def\reserved@a####1##1####2####3\@nil{
          \def\fim@procnr{####2}
          \ifx\fim@procnr\@nnil
            \@latex@error{Unknown processor \unexpanded{##1}}\@ehc
          \fi
        }%
        \reserved@a\includegraphics{0}\input{1}\include{2}##1{\@nil}\@nil
      }%
      \s@expandarg\reserved@a\fim@processor
    \fi;
  cmd/stuffbefore//;
  cmd/stuffafter//;
  cmd/fileext/tex/
    \ifpdf
      \ifinsetTF{#1}{,pdf,png,jpeg,jpg,mps,}
        {
          \edef\fim@graphicsext{#1}
        }{
          \def\fim@graphicsext{pdf}
        }
    \else
      \def\fim@graphicsext{eps}
    \fi;
  cmd/inputpaths/./
    \ifltxkeys@dec\else
      \def\fim@inputpaths{}
      \edef\fim@tempa{#1}
      \fim@stripbraces\fim@tempa
      % \openin will not take spaces in path or filename:
      \edef\fim@tempa{\s@expandarg\cptzapspaces\fim@tempa}
      \docommalist*\fim@tempa{
        \xifinsetTF{/\relax}{##1\relax}{
          \edef\fim@inputpaths{\fim@inputpaths\ifbracedTF{##1}{##1}{{##1}}}
        }{
          \@latex@error{Inputpath '##1' not ended with slash (/)}\@ehc
        }
      }
    \fi;
  cmd/inputpath/./\setaliaskey{inputpaths};
  cmd/scale/1;
  cmd/\needvalue{width}//;
  cmd/\needvalue{height}//;
  cmd/\needvalue{viewport}/0 0 100 100;
  bool/clip/true;
  choice/align.{
    center/\def\fim@align{center},
    left/\def\fim@align{flushleft},
    right/\def\fim@align{flushright},
    justified/\def\fim@align{fim@phantomenv}
  }/center;
}
% Why didn't I want to say \let\fim@phantomenv\relax?
\new@def*\fim@phantomenv{\relax}
\robust@def*\fim@stripbraces#1{%
  \cptstripallbrincs#1\despacecontent#1\cptstripallbrincs#1%
}
\robust@def*\importfiles{\cpt@testopt\fim@importfiles{}}
\robust@def*\fim@importfiles[#1]#2{%
  \usename{ltxkeys@\fim@setorlaunch keys}[KV]{importfiles}{#1}%
  % Some paths might have been suggested via \input@path
  % and/or \graphicspath. So we heed them here.
  \edef\fim@currpaths{%
    \ifdefTF\input@path\input@path{}%
    \ifdefTF\Ginput@path\Ginput@path{}%
    \fim@inputpaths
  }%
  \edef\fim@tempa{\ifmacroTF{#2}\expandcsonce\unexpanded{#2}}%
  \docommalist*\fim@tempa{%
    \def\currfile{##1}%
    \fim@stripbraces\currfile
    \def\siso@do####1{%
      \def\currpath{####1}%
      \fim@stripbraces\currpath
      \ifnum\fim@procnr=\z@pt
        \let\currfileext\fim@graphicsext
      \else
        \let\currfileext\fim@fileext
      \fi
      \edef\fileonpath{\currpath\currfile.\currfileext}%
      % Hmm, why don't I want to use \IfFileExists?
      \openin\@inputcheck\fileonpath\relax
      \ifcondTF\ifeof\@inputcheck\fi{}{%
        \typeout{File '\fileonpath' found}%
        \closein\@inputcheck
        \fim@doimport
      }%
    }%
    \s@expandarg\siso@@loop\fim@currpaths
  }%
}
\robust@def*\fim@doimport{%
  \fim@stuffbefore
  \begintoksgroup
  \ifcase\fim@procnr
    \toks@{%
      \begin{\fim@align}%
      \cptexpanded{%
        \noexpand\includegraphics
        [viewport=\fim@viewport,scale=\fim@scale,
        \ifcsemptyTF\fim@height{}{height=\fim@height,}%
        \ifcsemptyTF\fim@width{}{width=\fim@width,}%
        \iffim@clip,clip\fi]{\fileonpath}%
      }%
      \end{\fim@align}%
    }%
  \or
    \toks@{\input\fileonpath}%
  \or
    \toks@{%
      \let\fim@savpath\input@path
      \edef\input@path{{\currpath}}%
      \fiminclude\currfile
      \let\input@path\fim@savpath
    }%
  \fi
  \endtoksgroup
  \fim@stuffafter
}
\robust@def*\fiminclude#1{%
  \relax
  \ifnumcmpTF\@auxout=\@partaux{%
    \@latex@error{Command \noexpand\fiminclude cannot be nested}\@ehc
  }{%
    \edef\reserved@a{\cptzapspaces{#1}}%
    \s@expandarg\fim@include\reserved@a
  }%
}
\robust@def*\fim@include#1{%
  \xifinsetTF{.tex\relax}{#1\relax}{%
    \def\reserved@a##1.tex\@nil{%
      \def\fim@filename{##1}%
    }%
    \reserved@a#1\@nil
  }{%
    \def\fim@filename{#1}%
  }%
  \clearpage\relax
  \if@partsw
    % I don't know why LaTeX chose to do a loop here. We don't need it here:
    \xifinsetTF{,\fim@filename,}{,\fim@partlist,}%
      \@tempswatrue\@tempswafalse
  \else
    \@tempswatrue
  \fi
  \ifboolTF{@tempswa}{%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{\fim@filename.aux}}%
    \fi
    \let\@auxout\@partaux
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\openout\@partaux\fim@filename.aux
      \immediate\write\@partaux{\relax}%
    \fi
    \@input@{\fim@filename.tex}%
    \clearpage\relax
    \@writeckpt{\fim@filename}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\closeout\@partaux
    \fi
  }{%
    \deadcycles\z@pt
    \@nameuse{cp@\fim@filename}%
  }%
  \let\@auxout\@mainaux
}
\robust@def*\fimincludeonly#1{%
  \@partswtrue
  \cptexpandarg{\cptfiltermergecsv\fim@partlist}
    {\cptzapspaces{#1}}\nofilter
}
\cptonlypreamble\fimincludeonly
\makeatother

\fimincludeonly{subfile1a}
\begin{document}
\section{Test section}

\importfiles[
  processor   =includegraphics,
  viewport    =20 21 590 400,
  scale       =.25,
  inputpaths  ={D:/MyTempDoc/Path1/,D:/MyTempDoc/Path2/},
  stuffbefore =\bigskip\centering Importing \currfile\space from path \currpath\endgraf,
  stuffafter  =\endgraf\centering File import succeeded (\currfile).\endgraf
]{
  comet1
}

\importfiles[
  processor   =include,
  inputpaths  ={D:/MyTempDoc/Path1/,D:/MyTempDoc/Path2/}
]{
  subfile1a,subfile1b,subfile1c
}

\importfiles[
  processor   =\input,
  inputpaths  ={D:/MyTempDoc/Path1/,D:/MyTempDoc/Path2/}
]{
  subfile1a,subfile1b,subfile1c
}
\end{document}
```

This is only a partial listing of the code. The full version can handle stand-alone documents in the manner of *docmute* and *standalone* packages. I will release it as a package.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Remember to also update [Who are the package maintainers here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here) once you've packaged this up, as well as marking *this* original question as having led to the creation of a new package (as suggested by [Mark questions that led to creating a new package](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/mark-questions-that-led-to-creating-a-new-package)). Some [examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22This+question+led+to+a+new+package%22), if you're interested...

Comment: Please try to avoid code-only answers here. It would be great if you would add some basic explanation. Thank you.