# Create a document looping through images

Tags: macros, graphics, loops

I have about a hundred images named `001.png` to `123.png`. I want to create a document which includes each image in center of a page. i.e. a 123 page document with each image on a single page.

I know that doing this is possible using macros but I have no clue how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Will the document contain other things or just the images?

Comment: Here is a very similar question with a lot of approaches: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53458/10570

Comment: @Holle They are aimed at printing all files in some directories. Here the situation is simpler.

Comment: @egreg Thanks :) No, I don't need anything else other than the images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need only the images in the center of the page, just loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcounter{image}
\newcommand{\placeimages}[2]{%
  \setcounter{image}{#1}\addtocounter{image}{-1}%
  \loop\ifnum\value{image}<#2\relax
    \stepcounter{image}%
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \edef\current{\threedigits{image}}%
    \includegraphics{\current}%
    \\[12pt]\texttt{\current.png} % comment if you don't want the file name here
    \vfill
    \newpage
  \repeat
}
\newcommand{\threedigits}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{#1}<100 0\fi\ifnum\value{#1}<10 0\fi\arabic{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\centering
\placeimages{1}{123}
\end{document}
```

I used the `demo` option for `graphicx` just to avoid the need to populate my folder with mock images.