# How to put a series of figures in annex

Tags: floats, loops

I want to put 51 figures , with names 0001.png ,....., until 0051.png, in annex
ans I'm wondering if I can do something similar to this in latex .

for i series_of_figures;
put figure in annex , with the name_of_figures("0001.png", .., "0051.png") in the
caption .

I hope that you understood my problem and thanks for your help .

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74330/create-a-document-looping-through-images

Answer (score 4):

in the preamble put

```
\usepackage{capt-of}% or {caption} if you need more features
\newcounter{myfig}\setcounter{myfig}{1000}
\newcommand\eatone[1]{\expandafter\xeatone\the\value{myfig}}
\newcommand\xeatone[1]{}
```

Then in the document

```
\setcounter{myfig}{1000}
\loop
\stepcounter{myfig}
\par% or \begin{center} or whatever you need
\includegraphics{\eatone{myfig}
\captionof{figure}{image: \eatone{myfig}}
\par% or \end{center etc
\ifnum\value{myfig}<10052
\repeat
```