# Including many figures from a directory

Tags: graphics, automation

I have a large number of figures (~300) in a folder called 
      'allimages'. The figures are numbered fig1.eps, fig2.eps,.....fig300.eps. 
       I want to put all of them in latex such that 6 images appear on one page.
       What I know  to do is something like this

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Write the caption here.}
\vspace{0.0cm} \centering
\includegraphics[height=5.4cm]{allimages/fig1.eps}
\includegraphics[height=5.4cm]{allimages/fig2.eps}
\includegraphics[height=5.4cm]{allimages/fig3.eps}
\includegraphics[height=5.4cm]{allimages/fig4.eps}
\includegraphics[height=5.4cm]{allimages/fig5.eps}
\includegraphics[height=5.4cm]{allimages/fig6.eps}
\end{figure}
```

But doing like this will be time consuming. Is it possible to have some
    looping statement that makes it easier and help me skip long listing of
    figures. Thanks!

Comment: I would leave this task to my editor... Thus, what editor do you use?

Comment: I use texshop on mac platform. I use Xcode.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53458/inserting-figures-using-loops

Comment: If you have coding skills, just write a little program in your favorite language to generate the LaTeX source code.

Answer (score 17):

This looks easiest to do using `\foreach` from the `pgf` bundle. To get everything on separate pages, you probably need a couple of loops:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in {0,1,...,49}{%
  \begin{center}
    \foreach\y in {1,2,...,6}{%
      \includegraphics[height=5.4cm]{allimages/fig\numexpr 6 * \x + \y\relax}
    }%
    \captionof{figure}{Images \number\numexpr 6 * \x + 1\relax\space to
      \number\numexpr 6 * \x + 6\relax.}
  \end{center}
}
\end{document}
```

Doing all of this with floats will run out of space quite quickly (no intervening text), so I've used the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package to generate the appropriate text.

Comment: PDF file only has 1 page. Only a few images that are displayed. Other images are not displayed because it exceeds the page limit.

Comment: @EdyJo True: I've modified to use two loops and thus ensure that each page is 'just right'.

Comment: For me, it was necessary to put \the in front of numexp, after which this worked.

Comment: @ZachBoyd The example works _exactly as given above_

Comment: Great answer! Is it possible to generalize the solution in order to get the images even if they have random names? They'll be sorted, let's say, for example in alphabetical order...

Answer (score 7):

I used this shell snippet to generate the lines I needed.

```
for f in ./images/*.png; do echo "\\includegraphics[width=0.9\\linewidth]{images/$f}\\\\"; done;
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @BenCrowell, I solved this by writing a short MATLAB script to do this. In the hope that some future readers find it useful, I post it here.

```
fileID = fopen('./incl_img_latex.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fileID, '\\begin{figure}[h!]\n\\centering\n');

files = dir('./*.png');
for file = files'
    str = file.name;
    fprintf(fileID, '\\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\\textwidth}\n\\includegraphics[trim=45 180 70 210,clip,width=\\textwidth]{%s}\n\\end{subfigure}\n', str);
end

fprintf(fileID, '\\caption{C.}\n\\label{fig:}\n\\end{figure}');
fclose(fileID);
```