# Can I include all graphics in .png format of a folder?

Tags: graphics

I have a MATLAB program that generate many graphics in `.png` format in a folder
Can I include in my document, with a LaTeX code, all photo of a specific folder?

I can include all graphics with a equal scale and 3 graphics for rows in my document?

Comment: take a look at this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98748/including-many-figures-from-a-directory

Comment: @EladDen I find a LaTeX solution and my graphics name not have a standard name

Comment: just get the list into a tex file that you can input eg `ls *.png >pnglist.tex ` then it's easy to to `\includegraphics` on each. TeX can not natively do a directory listing. (or get matlab to generate the list if you prefer)