# Compiling a document to input more than 100 image files

Tags: macros, graphics

What I want to achieve is to compile a document of pictures in `.jpg` format into a `pdf` file. The problem is that I would not want to input all the files one by one. The files follow a pattern in there name:

```
MSD 2013-10-15 00-20-27-72
MSD 2013-10-15 00-20-32-86
```

How can this be achieved in an algorithmic manner? The files were created as snapshots of a few powerpoint presentations using `PrtSc` then converted to `.jpg` format. If you can notice, the only difference between the files would be the creation time.

Note upon creation, the image files should cover all the page width and page height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{MSD 2013-10-15 00-20-27-72} % should cover entire page 1
\includegraphics{MSD 2013-10-15 00-20-32-86} % should cover entire page 2
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

Using the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139195/10898) below, pdflatex shouts out:

```
! Dimension too large.
\pr@ship@end ...fi \endgroup {\dimen@ \ht \pr@box 
                                                  \ifdim \dimen@ <\z@ \dimen...
l.17 \end{document}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

! Dimension too large.
\pr@ship@end ...men@ \pr@bb@iv \dimen@ii =\dimen@ 
                                                  \global \pdfvorigin \dimen...
l.17 \end{document}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \dimen@ 

l.17 \end{document}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \dimen@ 

l.17 \end{document}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

! Dimension too large.
\pr@endbox ... \@undefined \voffset =-\ht \pr@box 
                                                  \hoffset =\z@ \fi \c@page ...
l.17 \end{document}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

[1
! Huge page cannot be shipped out.
\pr@endbox ...y \pr@markerbox }\else \box \pr@box 
                                                  \fi }\global \advance \pr@...
l.17 \end{document}

The page just created is more than 18 feet tall or
more than 18 feet wide, so I suspect something went wrong.

The following box has been deleted: []
```

Note each image file must be read from a folder.

Comment: Is there any pattern (like constant time gap) between two successive pictures taken so as to generate them or they are randomly taken ones (in this case one needs to read all `*.jpg` file names and store to reuse them i suppose)?

Comment: @texenthusiast The only pattern that I see would be the second each  snapshot was taken. That is, the second snapshot was taken a few seconds after the first. So the reading would be made on the basis of incremented time.

Comment: If the timestamps separated at random, the simplest strategy is to create a list and then adding `\printimage{` and `}` around the items; give a suitable definition of `\printimage`. Nesting three cycles that test, for every timestamp, the existence of the file with that name seems really a sledgehammer.

Comment: @egreg Would it take to much time to compile using the three cycle test? Would it be possible that the first run save to a `.aux` file then the second run compile the document.

Comment: The "Dimension too large" error might be due to missing information in the JPG files about resolution and dimensions. Sometimes it happens with JPG's.

Comment: I think @egreg is right. Try to add [width=0.9\linewidth] as an optional argument to `\includegraphics`. Next thing to check is the matter of spaces in filenames, YMMV depending on the operating system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapt the following. It works only on Windows. Compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex`. The same answer has been posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53467/19356).

### Code

```
% filename.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\edef\subdir{"Sub Dir/"}

\graphicspath{{\subdir}}
\immediate\write18{cmd /c dir /b \subdir\space *.png > imagelist.txt}


\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newread\reader
\openin\reader=imagelist.txt\relax
\begingroup
\endlinechar=-1\relax
\loop
    \readline\reader to \data
    \unless\ifeof\reader
            \filename@parse{\data}\noindent  
            \includegraphics[scale=.5,ext=.\filename@ext,width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{"\filename@base"}\newpage
\repeat
\endgroup
\closein\reader
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

### File Structure

[image]

[image]

### Output

To prove that I am *NOT* lying...

[image]

Comment: pdflatex complains by saying `! Dimension too large.`

Comment: The file simply does not compile. How is the data read? I do not see no `^^M`. Where is this located?

Comment: I am running your code as is. It creates the file `imagelist.txt` but complains afterwards.

Comment: Why does it print the filename beside each image?

Comment: I will look at it soon. I have been busy with end of semester wrap up and writing exams, terminal assignments, etc..... :-)

Comment: I can accept your answer just that the images do not cover the entire pages as the should be. That is I want the image to occupy all the white space in the paper somewhat like a background.

Comment: You don't have to do it. I suppose that with your code its a good start for me. Here it goes then :-)

Answer (score 14):

I've often done something like the following. Create (and save) a file, say myphotos.tex, with the required preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
```

At the command line (under windows) issue the following commands

```
for %x in (*.jpg) do echo \includegraphics{%x}\clearpage >> myphotos.tex
echo \end{document} >> myphotos.tex
```

Other operating systems can do things like this, although the syntax will differ. To get the photos expanded to fill the entire page, there are options to the \includegraphics command that will scale the pictures. For example, use

```
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]
```

instead of `\includegraphics` in the above.

Answer (score 2):

This does the three loops; the arguments to `\imageloop` are the “common part”, then the starting minute and the ending minute for the search. If also the hour changes one needs another loop.

I commented the “real” printing function, replacing it with a test. The loops are quite fast on my machine, but, with `\IfFileExists` and the printing of the images, processing will be rather slow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% #1 = fixed part
% #2 = starting minute
% #3 = ending minute
\NewDocumentCommand{\imageloop}{mmm}
 {
  \azet_imageloop:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azet_imageloop:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #2 } { 1 } { #3 }
   {
    \azet_imageloop_seconds:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azet_imageloop_seconds:nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { 59 }
   {
    \azet_imageloop_hundredths:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azet_imageloop_hundredths:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { 99 }
   {
    \azet_imageloop_print:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \azet_imageloop_two:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #1 < 10 } { 0 } #1
 }

%\cs_new_protected:Npn \azet_imageloop_print:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
% {
%  \IfFileExists
%   {
%    #1-\azet_imageloop_two:n{#2}-\azet_imageloop_two:n{#3}-\azet_imageloop_two:n{#4}.jpg
%   }
%   {
%    \clearpage
%    \vspace*{\fill}
%    \includegraphics
%     {
%      #1-\azet_imageloop_two:n{#2}-\azet_imageloop_two:n{#3}-\azet_imageloop_two:n{#4}.jpg
%     }
%    \vfill
%   }
%   {} % nothing if the file doesn't exist
% }

%%% just for testing
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azet_imageloop_print:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \par
  #1-\azet_imageloop_two:n{#2}-\azet_imageloop_two:n{#3}-\azet_imageloop_two:n{#4}.jpg
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\imageloop{MSD 2013-10-15 00}{20}{20}
\end{document}
```

Here are the first few lines:

[image]

Comment: This created a document with 131 pages and the three counters just seem to be increasing. How is this reading all the jpg files in the folder and then inputing them for compilation? Thanks for the input.

Comment: @azetina You can see a commented definition for `\azet_imageloop_print:nnnn` which is what you'll really be using. The definition used for the sample is just for testing correctedness of the tentative file names to be passed to `IfFileExists`. (I fixed an error in the commented code.)

Comment: It now produces 44 pages with no image output in the pdf file. Weird.

Comment: @azetina Of course, spaces in file names must be removed.

Comment: You mean that I should replace the space in `MSD 2013-10-15 00-20-27-72.jpg` before running your code? That is between MSD and 2013 and 15 and 00?

Comment: @azetina Yes, spaces in file names and TeX don't go along well.

Comment: If I replace the spaces with a `-` will your code still compile?

Comment: @azetina In my experiment it does.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a script to generate a .tex file with just

```
\doit{MSD 2013-10-15 00-20-27-72} 
\doit{MSD 2013-10-15 00-20-32-86}
```

(I know how to do it in *nix, not in Windows). Than use a file with in the preamble:

```
\newcommand\doit[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{#1}\vfill\eject}
```

or something similar.

The error you see seems more a problem of a missing width (maybe the jpgs have a very big pixel count?)

Answer (score 1):

```
\def \SD #1-#2-#3-#4-#5-#6#7{\includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]
  {MSD #1-#2-#3-#4-#5-#6#7.jpg}\vfill\newpage}
  % Each "-" will match a hyphen "-" in the filename
\catcode`M=0 % M is now conveninetly synonym to \
\input{imagelist.tex} % MSD is like \SD so each line of this file now calls \SD.
\catcode`M=11 % clean up of M.
```

If each line of the file imagelist.txt contains also the suffix .jpg, then you should replace "SD #1-#2-#3-#4-#5-#6#7" by "SD#1.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is not a TeX-Solution, but I would use a small Python-Script. The advantage would be, that it would be easily adjustable, if you need to browse through different directories or want to include further features (i.e. read some description for each picture from a textfile and add it as a caption).

Put the following in a file `picmaker.py` (and make it executable, if you are not using Windows).

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import glob
import subprocess

texfile = ['''\\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage{graphicx}
\\begin{document}''']

for pic in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    texfile.append('\\includegraphics{{{0}}}'.format(pic[:-4]))

texfile.append('\\end{document}')

finalfile = "\n".join(texfile)
with open('tmp.tex', 'w') as f:
    f.write(finalfile)

subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'tmp.tex'])
```

Execute it via `python picmaker.py`.

If you need further adjustments, such as textwidth, you can easily add them.

Note that `\` has to be replaced by `\\`, `{` by `{{` and `}` by `}}`.

Note also, that `'*.jpg'` is case-sensitive.