# Unable to include "large" code in lyx files

Tags: errors, lyx, code, sourcecode

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116944/insert-programming-code-in-a-lyx-document) question I was able to insert (Java) code into my lyx document. However, when I try to visualize (export it as a .pdf) the following error comes up:

```
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet. Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

The related questions I found, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139189/compiling-a-document-to-input-more-than-100-image-files) one and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124442/tikz-when-i-use-the-draw-let-in-command-to-draw-a-trivial-arc-i-get-dimens) one are related to including images into a document. Why does lyx show the same error when working with code snippets?

The issue appears in the following case:

[image: long code 1]

The error message:

[image: long code 2]

A shortened example can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2DGqsAqvhBteGFOMjVrUkVpY1U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example? see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: I actually found out why. When copy/pasting from Intellij the white spaces are discarded and the code appears to lyx to be a very long string that it doesn't like.

Comment: @scottkosty No, I was wrong, I'm updating the question. I cannot really post a minimal example since the error occurs when the code to be inserted is of a certain length.

Comment: I see. Are you able to upload an example to dropbox or google drive or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I'm adding the document now.

Comment: @scottkosty Added it now.

Comment: For me the example you posted compiles fine to PDF.

Comment: Yes, it does compile but the lines do not split accordingly. I mean my code is hafway outside the page.

Comment: Ah yes I can reproduce but in your question you say you get errors. Is this a separate question?

Comment: I get errors when I have lines that are too long.

Comment: @scottkosty nvm I've fixed it using the smallest available font size, adding new lines after each line of code and shortening each line to about 100 characters and have also checked the Break long lines options in the Settings menu.

Comment: OK please add an answer to this question and accept it. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: You seriously want some kind of automatic line breaks added to your code.

Comment: No. I mean you can't break up code and still expect it to run (definitions method contracts and invocations may be affected). The initial version did not display the lines at all once they reached the right margin of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by splitting all lines of code with new lines (when copied from intellij all '\n' characters have been removed and this cause a problem as the source was too long). 
Then, by right clicking the source code("Program listing") and going to the **"Settings"** I've changed the following:

- in the Style menu box picked smallest font type (not tiny)
- changed the family type to "Roman"
- checked the break long lines box

It is important that each line has no more than 100 characters, otherwise when converting to .pdf (luatex) the lines might not fit within the pages of the exported .pdf.