# Make 3x4 figures from pictures in a folder

Tags: floats, folders

Assume you have 777 pictures. You want to present them on 3x4 A4s.
Doing `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` takes much time and space.

Is there any other way to present these figures in a folder in such a way?
Like make this presentation from all these figures in the this folder.

Comment: If you want a caption for each sub-picture, you should use package `subfigure`. Otherwise, if pictures are sorted by name you can make a `tikz` script but is not so easy.

Comment: @marchetto `subfigure` is deprecated; the newer `subfig` or preferably the newer-still `subcaption` should be used instead.

Comment: How your figure files are named? Is there a symantec naming scheme adopted?

Comment: @PaulGessler: you're right, I was wrong to write the name. Correct name is subfig

Comment: The names are in this form: "Screen Shot 2014-02-20 at 09.16.33".

Comment: The time of screenshot is enough for the order. So I have them in order already. Only presentation is needed. Probably later, I can add captions. So would be ok if that possibility later too.

Comment: I think that Make a script with a so variable name is not convenient.

Comment: What's “3x4 A4s”? Anyway, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53458/inserting-figures-using-loops might help

Comment: why should it be necessary to use the `figure` environment`?  putting `\includegraphics` commands directly into a `tabular` environment, or even just in rows of three, spaced out evenly across the page, should be possible.  (you'll have to make sure that they are all the same size, or create a `minipage` wrapper that enforces this, which can be done with a macro.)  only the last page might need some additional attention, since 777 isn't a multiple of 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your pictures are in a pdflatex compatible format.

Make a liste called liste.dat with the name of your files sorted in the right order. For example :`ls *jpg | sort > liste.dat`

Then compile this file called fichier.tex with pdflatex :

```
\documentclass[a4apaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0cm, bottom=0cm, left=0cm, right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tikz,filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{liste.dat}{\Liste}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{liste.dat}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\rows} {%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index] 0}\of{\Liste} 
    \let\Name\pgfplotsretval
    % If there is a second column with caption for each file
    %\pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index] 1}\of{\Liste} 
    %\let\Caption\pgfplotsretval 

    \begin{figure}[!p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{\Name}
    % if there is a caption column
    %\caption{\Caption}
    \end{figure}    
    \clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

then compile this other file called picture.tex with pdflatex :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[page=-,nup=3x4]{fichier.pdf}
\end{document}
```

And you should have a file with 12 (3*4) images per page.

If the file.dat contains a second column with the captions for each file or empty, you can have them at the same time.

Comment: I started to consider this code in OSX (which I have now only) and noticed no pgfplots in MacTex: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/177569/15504

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use

```
\usepackage{subfig}
...


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 1x1}.\label{fig:001}]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file001}} \quad
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 1x2}.\label{fig:002}]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file002}} \quad
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 1x3}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file003}} \quad
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 1x4}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file004}} \\
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 2x1}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file005}} \quad
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 2x2}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file006}} \quad
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 2x3}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file007}} \quad
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 2x4}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file008}} \\
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 3x1}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file009}} \quad
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 3x2}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file010}} \quad
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 3x3}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file011}} \quad
    \subfloat[][\emph{Figure 3x4}.]
        {\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{file012}} \\
    \caption{This is the caption.}
    \label{fig:subfig}
\end{figure}
```