# Can I defend against "Dimension too large" errors?

Tags: errors, dimensions

I'm trying to debug the error in ["Dimension too large" error with too many tikzmarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491381/86) which involves getting a `Dimension too large` error (duh).  I have my suspicions as to what is causing it, and also a suspicion that there will be situations that mean that I can't eliminate the possibility of it occurring altogether.

Is there any way to defend against this error?  What I would really like is something like a `try ... except ...` block.  Does that exist?

Here's a MWE to play around with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newdimen\ad
\newdimen\bd

\ad=16383pt\relax
\bd=2\ad

\showthe\ad
\showthe\bd

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Essentially, I would like to be able to wrap the `\bd=2\ad` in something that allows me to define an alternative if it threatens to trigger the dreaded `Dimension too large` error.

Comment: Some time ago I asked about the [`try ... except ...` thing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412891/134574), but it doesn't appear to exist (unfortunately).

Comment: Can't you use something like the `fpu` or `fp` libraries to check first whether or not the value is too large?

Answer (score 8):

Using `l3fp` to make a wrapper macro which checks if the dimension exceeds `\c_max_dim` (or `\maxdimen` or `16383.99999pt`) and uses a fallback value (which I set to `\c_max_dim` itself) in case the assignment exceeds it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \trydim #1
  {
    \exp_args:Nf
      \__loopspace_try_dim:nn { \fp_eval:n {#1} } {#1}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__loopspace_try_dim:nn #1 #2
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { abs(#1) } > \c_max_dim
      {
        % Exception code
        \dim_use:N \c_max_dim
      }
      {
        % Success code
        % Using \dim_eval:n to maintain TeX's behaviour,
        % but you can replace by #1, which is the result of \fp_eval:n
        \dim_eval:n {#2}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newdimen\ad
\newdimen\bd

\ad=\trydim{16383pt}
\bd=\trydim{2\ad}

\showthe\ad
\showthe\bd

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This prints to the terminal:

```
> 16383.0pt.
l.31 \showthe\ad

?
> 16383.99998pt.
l.32 \showthe\bd

?
```

The "exception code" is what you intend to do if the value exceeds `\c_max_dim`. I used the `\dim_use:N \c_max_dim` to get the maximum value possible.

The "success code", you guessed, is when the value is within the allowed range. I used `\dim_eval:n {#2}` because there are controversies on the accuracy of `l3fp`, so the result obeys TeX's rules as long as they are valid. Of course you can change that to `\fp_eval:n {#2}` (or, for the matter, `#1`, which is the `\fp_eval:n`'ed dimension).

---

Or, if you prefer, an inline fallback value:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \trydim #1 #2
  {
    \exp_args:Nf
      \__loopspace_try_dim:nnTF { \fp_eval:n {#1} }
        {#1} {#2}
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__loopspace_try_dim:nn #1 { T, F, TF }
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { abs(#1) } > \c_max_dim
      { \prg_return_false: }
      { \prg_return_true: }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newdimen\ad
\newdimen\bd

\ad=\trydim{16383pt}{0pt}

\bd=\trydim{2\ad}{10pt}

\showthe\ad
\showthe\bd

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Which prints:

```
> 16383.0pt.
l.31 \showthe\ad

?
> 10.0pt.
l.32 \showthe\bd

?
```

Comment: It's not the _accuracy_ of `l3fp` that's a bit interesting with dimens, it's how you decide to deal with the conversion: there are equally-valid paths with different outcomes. Personally, I'd always use `\dim_to_fp:n` for these.

Comment: Looks fabulous!  Thank you.

Comment: @JosephWright But here, since we expect a `Dimension too large`, `\dim_to_fp:n` could fail, right?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, that's true: I just meant in general. (The team are actively discussing what the right approach is.)

Comment: @JosephWright Oh, right, about the other question. I'm curious about that now :-) (thanks for the pointer to `\dim_to_fp:n`; I didn't know it before)