# Checking if an integer is a member of an integer list

Tags: macros, strings, comparison, number, l3fp

Is there any way to check whether an integer is a member of a list of integer numbers and return a boolean?

I found this neat solution, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260909/23594) that does a great job. It checks whether a string exists in a list of strings:

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{xstring}
> \newcommand\IfStringInList[2]{\IfSubStr{,#2,}{,#1,}}
> \begin{document}
>     \IfStringInList{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{True}{False}
> \end{document}
> ```

However, it does return a string not a boolean "true" or "false" and caused me some difficulty which is posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501749/23594).

Let's call the macro I would like to have `\ISMEMBER`. My goal is to use `\ISMEMBER` and examine whether an integer is in the list and depending on whether it is or not, perform some tasks, as an example:

```
\fpeval{ \ISMEMBER{1}{1,2,3,4,5} ? \MACRO_FOR_MEMBERS : \MACRO_FOR_NON_MEMBERS }
```

Is such functionality possible?

Comment: I think an answer to one of my questions might be helpful here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496671/85504

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use do a comma-separated list parser to loop through the list of items and check if the given item is present in the list. Since the comma-separated list can be read by using a delimited macro, this can be done expandably, allowing you to plug the macro into `\fpeval` to get the syntax you want.

Using `expl3` (you are loading it with `xfp` anyway) something like this would solve the problem:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \afp_int_ismember:nn #1#2 { p, T, F, TF }
  { \__afp_ismember_loop:nw {#1} #2 , \q_recursion_tail , \q_recursion_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__afp_ismember_loop:nw #1#2,
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn {#2}
      { \prg_return_false: }
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {#2}
      { \use_i_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:nw { \prg_return_true: } }
      { \__afp_ismember_loop:nw {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The code above defines a conditional `\afp_int_ismember:nn(TF)`, whose first argument is the item to check, and the second is the comma-separated list. The macro starts by expanding `\__afp_ismember_loop:nw`: this macro takes the item to be tested (`#1`) and the first item in the list, delimited by a `,` (`#2`). The macro tests the equality of `#1` and `#2` using `\int_compare:nNnTF` and issues `\prg_return_true:` if they are equal or calls `\__afp_ismember_loop:nw` for the next item. If the end of the list is found (*i.e.,* `\q_recursion_tail` is grabbed), then the function issues `\prg_return_false:` because no match was found for `#1`.

The code above can be tweaked to replace `\int_compare:nNnTF` by a generic equality comparison function. If you do that you can define wrappers around `\__afp_ismember_loop:nw` to create `ismember` functions for different data types. The code below does that and defines two functions: `\afp_int_ismember:nn(TF)` (using `\int_compare:nNnTF`) and `\afp_str_ismember:nn(TF)` (using `\str_if_eq:eeTF`). Doing that you can even test if I'm a member of the Beatles!

> [image]

To use the function in `\fpeval` you just need the predicate form (`\afp_int_ismember_p:nn`) of the conditional function:

```
\fpeval{ \afp_int_ismember_p:nn {1} {1,2,3,4,5} ? 123 : 321 }
```

And the string version would also work here:

```
\fpeval{ \afp_str_ismember_p:nn {Phelype} {George,John,Paul,Ringo} ? 123 : 321 }
```

---

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xfp}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Core code for the membership test
\cs_new:Npn \__afp_ismember_loop:Nnw #1#2#3,
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn {#3}
      { \prg_return_false: }
    #1 {#2} {#3}
      { \use_i_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:nw { \prg_return_true: } }
      { \__afp_ismember_loop:Nnw #1 {#2} }
  }
% Wrapper for testing integers
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \afp_int_ismember:nn #1#2 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \__afp_ismember_loop:Nnw \__afp_int_isequal:nnTF {#1} #2 ,
    \q_recursion_tail , \q_recursion_stop
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__afp_int_isequal:nn #1#2 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {#2}
      { \prg_return_true: }
      { \prg_return_false: }
  }
% Wrappers for testing strings
  % With expansion
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \afp_str_ismember:ee #1#2 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \__afp_ismember_loop:Nnw \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1} #2 ,
    \q_recursion_tail , \q_recursion_stop
  }
  % Without expansion
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \afp_str_ismember:nn #1#2 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \__afp_ismember_loop:Nnw \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1} #2 ,
    \q_recursion_tail , \q_recursion_stop
  }
% Sample commands
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \IntIsmember } { m m }
  {
    \afp_int_ismember:nnTF {#1} {#2}
      { #1~is~member~of~`#2' }
      { #1~is~\emph{not}~member~of~`#2' }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \StrIsmember } { m m }
  {
    \afp_str_ismember:nnTF {#1} {#2}
      { #1~is~member~of~`#2' }
      { #1~is~\emph{not}~member~of~`#2' }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\IntIsmember{1}{1,2,3}

\IntIsmember{4}{1,2,3}

\StrIsmember{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}

\textbf{\StrIsmember{Phelype}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fpeval{ \afp_int_ismember_p:nn {1} {1,2,3,4,5} ? 123 : 321 }\par
\fpeval{ \afp_str_ismember_p:nn {Phelype} {George,John,Paul,Ringo} ? 123 : 321 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: That answer makes me wonder why there isn't an expandable `\clist_if_in:nn(TF)`

Comment: @siracusa There could be... Please, [do ask](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues) :-) The only problem I see is that we would possibly need a `\clist_str_if_in:nn(TF)` and a `\clist_tl_if_in:nn(TF)` (and potentially others) because the only `\clist`y thing here is that the function looks up something in a `clist`: the actual data type in the `clist var` would need to be queried... Perhaps `\str_if_in_clist:nn` and `\tl_if_in_clist:nn` and `\int_if_in_clist:nn`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Very nice! Any reason you use `\cs_new:Npn` instead of `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` for the document-level commands? Is it that you don't want to load `xparse`, maybe? Or... are you a rebel? :)

Comment: @frougon A rebel, probably ;-) Actually I didn't even think of it: the `\IntIsmember` and `\StrIsmember` commands are just examples. But you're right, `xparse` is better here. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

Something like this? The macro name is inspired by the Mathematica command `MemberQ`, and the code comes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498576/121799). This solution does not require any packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifmember
\makeatletter% for \@for see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100684/121799
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498576/121799
\newcommand{\MemberQ}[2]{\global\memberfalse%
\@for\next:=#1\do{\ifnum\next=#2\global\membertrue\fi}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\MemberQ{1,2,3,4}{2}
\ifmember 2 is in list \fi

\MemberQ{1,2,3,4}{5}
\ifmember 5 is in list\else%
5 is not in the list\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, an answer of @marmot that does not include anything from Ti*k*Z!?! I MUST READ IT.

Comment: @manooooh This is a great solution and also compact. I wish I could select two accepted answers. Can this be used inside a `\fpeval`? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AFP No, it cannot because it isn't expandable (`\@for` isn't expandable because it does assignments, and `\membertrue` and `\memberfalse` are also assignments, so not expandable). The expandability of `l3fp` allows you to use it virtually anywhere TeX expects a number (see [this trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492353/134574), for example). The downside of this expandability is that _everything_ inside an expression _must_ be expandable too.